# Slice the source code (Cops)

Tags: cops-and-robbers

[Robbers thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242618/slice-the-source-code-robbers)

## Cops

### Understanding slicing

Remember, slices are zero-indexed. Take this slice: [2:]. If the string is "abcde", the result is "cde" because the slice basically means "get all elements with an index greater than 2." Let's try [1:3]. If there is an end slice, the end slice is not included. (excluded) Therefore, the result is "bc". What about [::2]? [::2] means "take every second element", so the result is "ace".

*Note: This is not a list of all the slicing features. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).*

Cops, your job is to write to a program, that when sliced, will input a string and reverse it. The slice could be something like `[::-1][2::6]` which means "reverse the code, then get each sixth char starting from index 2."

The unsliced program must be valid code, and it does not need to do anything. It may not take any input. A valid program is a program that does not have anything in STDERR.

You must specify the number of slices. Both the unsliced and the sliced programs must be non-empty. You must include a slice.

### Scoring

Your score is the following:
$$
(sum of start slices*2 + sum of end slices*2 + sum of step slices*3) * code size in bytes before slice
$$

All fragments not included default to zero. Negative slices are made positive (-1 => 1, -2 => 2, ...)

Lowest score wins.

The tiebreaker is code size. Cracked answers are ineligible for scoring or winning.

Comment: I feel like there's a pretty good argument that any chain of slices can be compressed into one.

Comment: @dingledooper Yeah, just like any product of cycles can be compressed into a permutation. But that's beside the point. I agree with you in all seriousness, and I believe the challenge should probably be scored by the simplicity of the slice instead, that is, the numbers involved, whether it's a slice like `5:`, `::5`, `4::5`, `6:5::3` etc.

Comment: Why larger code is better for score?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 1026 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242818/84290)

```python
"""#ipepfrvr iai nln t(tT=4(rp9iur2nei3p:n)u t4t 
#(pd2)re3[if7:n 4:tg8: (2-=o31e)7]v:4)ae0;lx%p e3r(c2i"(8n "1t "7(e.3ixj0nio2pti1u"n7t)(4(#me) ae[npe:o(v:tcv- hv1 ra]o,aapmanealdnpl" (lN s(o u"pum¤e ,#!ez#"xi%)ip¤;t(#p m%roa¤irp"n (#t o!((r"i d¤ne,#pv"!uai%tlk#()b")(g")"m#;1!)p4b3r"g3i)i3n
n1t#m3( !3)N\3;O"1i
T3n 33p 33u &1to*3(pV3)e\3;n"1p "3p )3ro,3rr91i 93i1*3n5[3n*o1t ]3ti)3(d)3(()1i )3i )3ni
3nnx1pt=3p(03u 
3uic1tnl3tta3((s3(is1)n 3)tf3[ :3[(
1:i 3:nd3-te31(f1]  3]i_3)d_3)(d1; e3p l3pp_3pr_1pi(3pns3pte3p(l1p f3pp)3pr:3pig1rn(3rtx3r()3r[
1r1y3r1,3r1x3r]=1r[f3r:(3i1)3i2,1i373i] 3i[i3i:f1i5 3n503n5 3n5e1n5l3n-s3t1e3t1 1t123t1 3t1i3t1f1t1 3i103i1 3i1e1i1l3n]s3n)e3n) 1n)83p) 3p)i3p)f1p) 3p)03p# 3p1e)u1l3u;s3u
e3u
 ;u
33u
 3u
i3t
f;t  et 0et  et evt lvt svt eat  at 4at  lt ilt flt  (t 0(t  (p exp lxposxpoe)po )po6)pk ;pkiepkfelk elk0xl( xl)exl)lel)selieeli cli6cei ceii(eif(ed (ed0xed xadexadl)ads)a(e)s( ;s)78s) 7s)i4spf3s. 2e.09er 8e.e4e.l7eis9e.e2e. 3
n27
. 4
.i9
tf2
. 7
.03
( 4
.e9
.l2#is3p.e7T. 4rn99"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZNRbuM4DIbffQrGRhdSkQaW6Y4TG73C7EuxL5mg8MR0hxtFJmQ58Ox5epJerMtgHj78NPlDEkVZfqdfU8C9xK@vPM8LFpIx3iJwzxB8gGTS60ttohx4iVUgRmmDXSDVCbLCyFDZSHjksWkD1G1637dgqqeXCR3Z5nRra9tT2fn1QYAwmnPFudkHyF2CvDG0Q17/LQNPlSR2Sx6aZE1tiitZ6OkYhNrJ3Np0vj3Br5uD2J@mbd/LtQ/U@yGIz8H47zCbCZZcluvnB8G22NB/Rb7yg2X5/OiSKQSuD3HqPz84Sh7AFAmmjTExZxg@PwJtC7nlm6Xnh@QvhbE/c2vec5tfi85trNQ/MebvyJYxZMGl4ooGNmi//8Du79xx9ooBEEVZ4C@Xpkc08g9a0nrInUCuNYtx2mKMB8dwQHaPGJ6PGB4nvYsTJrZoBsVYrVu8EzjDEFYn6QXFlLp2hgufXQoeU@rVO6Ph2Vnd3KYRj9Di0WSuZcA2DPiUCJ0Z3QkAT/yGdlDM4DqdhYBHkTeU@OaEDUqYUdQvxut5R61ZrbUo/O5iMBjTqvPTHo6Zi@43Rqe9OM2dXlw8jhhboz3puautY2yQT4B8ZOR2dPwM2mup3JVcePYYnmZMjhRwyVV3VVgZ3T1mVyp3JcdO/acZgyUFXLB7FAuKvkc7uj9xiVKo6sNb1L90My4ZKdAtGd5V0fWzsUsAlKCkP0q3BF6ZFeo1p9R39QlYGRUw6jd31Xe86t2tMs0KWZlA@WblAp1cmOQykr@AUq7ewOotKZ68nckzKXD2/O1MqsRsiEdDAyjlqrr2Ayne9sNse0N2NtDNttnPFprZcj3LiPMOKtqVB4qwpx3VtPMN8XzQWPOAWaiabAd1tuNDlsZKY/0uMTP3HB2yna8K1nnvqHlVXwyHg/7@X1//Aw)

Uhh, have fun I guess. Still not super difficult. (one slice is enough, just like for every other answer). This code contains non-ascii unicode characters. Those should be treated as one unit (not be broken up). If you use pythons slicing, and the source code is not a bytestring, you should be fine.

Comment: Great reference!

Comment: @ophact whats the reference?

Comment: @BgilMidol a subslice of my answer is a substring of opchats answer

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242818/64121)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 181 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242623/106710)

```python
if   True:  print =eval ('  exit')# not  open   u 
exit or  ( eval)('14')
# NO
   
open  or 15* id(  int( int(int (int( id(  print( print([111][:123][:55555-11111111111]))))))))#11;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETv@YqBHLIRPKy1l0p/wV68lR4EIwYkCSEV@/UxaQvOYZYdHjNhSS/vmpztE8AtzqYDQrQuoTef@xukAPO1SWkJ5xPgg3EFnSFqDB8BQkU1KT4rLSSugyiE2MgCcHuAfRBQamm12k/bV/N1kPYzMvM0dnxqirdVR/5r0rsk8yXnHw)

Much easier than you think.

Slices: 1

Comment: Are you sure that there is input?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena If sliced, then yes.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242623/84290)

Comment: @AnttiP Great job! I knew I could have hidden it better.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 37 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242652/)

```
[,[[[+]>+[>++<+],[-].[<],[--.+[<]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/Wic6Olo71k472k5b20Y7VidaN1Yv2gZE6@ppAxkg8P@/oZGxiSkA)

1 Slice. Easy as the question itself make cops easily brute-forced

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242633/106959)

Comment: [Actually cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242652/84290)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 22 bytes, 1 slice, [cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242632/78850)

```
Ǎ⟑(hn\++Rnẋ::ws=ß⅛)¾∑t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHjeKfkShoblxcKytSbuG6izo6d3M9w5/ihZspwr7iiJF0IiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISJd)

For once I decided not to take advantage of some strange quirk of Vyxal that only I know exists and instead did a normal Vyxal cop answer. Enjoy!

Lyxal found the exact slice I used. Nice.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242632/78850)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes, 1 slice, [cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242618/slice-the-source-code-robbers/242642#242642)

```
»ż⟩" 3⅛⇩Cİµ×∷İ»kPτ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu8W84p+pXCIgM+KFm+KHqUPEsMK1w5fiiLfEsMK7a1DPhCIsIiIsIiJd)

Should be fairly easy but I'll see if y'all get this one.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242642/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 10000 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242651/84290)

```python
#u]]nppt]1ii:up]ppnt[::((pn-)p]]nt)1:u[[]1it][p-n--p]t1i:t-p[(1i(-[tp)upppti--[upnt::p):up]:]1)(u1nn[-p1)tt:ppnt1np](-)()puu(:-p[[u(:::1pt:u)[11[ui][]ip(pn)]pptpiip(-u(t-:uittp-t-p-it-u:1n-[:p]n:[upup:n)pup-:tun[n:pn)i:ptu:1i)ippnpnpu):pn:]:nn:1-ip)1p(t:t(-ttn]t:p)(:u[[]t[)utu::(i--tt)1p:u1)p(u(ppt-[)([u]u-[p]ptitu)[t:iii-]ui(-ipp-pppn(ip-(-pip]nu(ui1-)p(pu-1n)up[-p:-tppp1u:t-:p1tnp((:1[n[-nt1]):t[))i-t:ppn:[[1)p(]1uu1p(1(un(uupi[:]])]):pi-pp1u(t(pp1-]uu]u[n-t:ti-1u1-iut]1))(tpp)n-pi[u1-))t(u[1n)[ut:ppn-:1t11ttn(1]iupi[p)11]pt1]ntni:]ipu(u-n-i(p[1)(]i1:i]t]n:]1:[p[:]nu[[11)t]1)i]n[it:p]:tp))()n:p-(tt-tpup(1])n1]1nu)([u11i:u)pp1(pp)tnp)[((:[[1[][1[()ipnp)u[1[p1un)])[(p(nu[[(ip:1:--tttp[u1[p(ptnp1tpp(1p[]-]]i[-nuntnpun(1t:tp-ppp1tt[n[]uun]np1u):p)pt[[-n:[1i[n(uu[n:i(t:p)[p-:pi)(pp1--]p)u)t)nupt[[)(u(i)[:](tp-[([p-:np]-[uii--u:)::p-p:]t1i](-)p1tp1p)[tu]-[-tt[n[1-]]1(i(t](i(uppup-)ii-u[u)p[i[)(nt([]i]1[:u1])i]1]u[np[ntnut]i1)t)tii(n]-1pt)itp)p]p-p1unu:n]((1]-]-[(-](tnpupp:-p[u][:]upp:tu1p1t11u1u[]pptpui1pt[)i(i]pi[n)]u1iu[i1u[p:(ppp)(:u(p)(inn](-)[tnp[p-uun)(-putpp)-ttui:1u[pit(p1p]-:[[n[uu)1i:tpu[u)n(ppiup:[)ppip(tp:)t(1t]](::)[n1:1tn(utu[[---)n]npp-tpp]in](::):tpt1)(pt1tu:[-ppupi(-u)-:1t(upn-(1-p:)):1t]:pt-p(p(t):-1u:[u[:i)():1(1))tn[utn:n1)t1pt1iu:)[tp-(:(:-(1:[)pu]-in)p)[]]tpp1tnnp)-pu1i[pu-ip]ii]pt:i](t()[1p(-)-t[pu[()i[t1-)tp)pn::pupnpipti-:[):upi1[1]i:]nu:p]p:[pt([t[pu-n1((-](](p[iu-u1t)u)p)1iiuu)[)]-nun]]pn:[t[1[nnputu-un]npt:u(up))):11)1]i(:n[)(-[t)]tip[ppi[-p:p)::-]n:](p-()t(ppp)p)tnp)1uu:(nipuitt)-:1--1p]un-pp:ui:up:t:n)n]]n)[(:tu]ippi]:[tp1in:])[]t-)i]1-p-)[ttp]u1:(1in):(pppipi:p11)p[u11:)i](-)i:):np-[1ppn:n[:-:[p))i]ntt-[ip(-pip11ptp:)n)pp-(]:[:t:)p-p(u1)p[n-[[]p(utup])i11:t(](p[1-(pp-:npn[:p-u1itu([[up][in(p-pup)t:(u]ui-pp[[t::((pu]]pt1u[:()t:n):-p]-uui]pt[:][1)t1t:(p(ipnpn[-1:))-[]pn1]]:in((ni)niu](-npn(n-:-:n:ut():)pp]1uu)p1::]i()[n))i]])(:[inin[]t-t--npi(ni-1t)-:])--:ut]pn1(tupp]np1:p)]u[:[(1iu)1-ip:1[tp1[p(:p])1u1-1nu1-p1-1t)-pu1(:1)]up1[]n::)]--()pp[1pu-)p1)p1np-]in:)pipt[t1t1n)1:(p:]tni[i(uu:u-11]p1(])nup(tpnp]p[)n:1-[p-1t:-:](u)1it[]-u1ip1]1pi-pii)[)(n(tt:p()(([]n-ttp(i([p1()np)]t1]t:u]nt1p(1)[1puunit)(u[ipp)(p])tpp]p-ii:n:-p][pu[-t:(::i[:u]ti)(:u][(:pp)ni([ip[][1[i1)p(pp(11)]1ti1p]-nn)](u(t(nui1pun)pp:u([[nppi]1]]ti:t-(p1[it:t):tn-(pu1i)pp(:ttnpi(]p]-[][p)u[-u)nini(i[:p:]-i)(t1--:1[:[[:u)[-pi:[)[-ppp)u)u(upp)]pt1[ti](()1[p(-upp(1(i][p:1u]t(i(1]u(u(p-::1tt]n]p:t11p[n1()ni-[n-n-p1-:::t[(pp[u]))n)))p)upnptup]:-:[:(-((-[[p-t[n[]:u]nn-1t[p-t[-)t-pp1iu])-:p:p)-p[:(n(::in[pt:upip):-u:][u[1--up1p:)(-:[(in)1(t]-:t:p:)t)[1:t)unp:-pituiu1[n[-np-p]:(ppup[np[)p)-u[i-u-([)(](tpi-n)(ntpp:p:t())ntp)[ui-uu:[1up:1][:p:p(n]u1t:]iin[tn[ipn)pip-u])t)t-]tp(:1:i]tp))tuu:1pupi([nu]pu:]])p(u-:1pii1-(1[:tunn[pp(up(p(pin)ptp-)]]]p)(tu(p-p1)11:i]i]i-:1it1[(tn1n([]()ut-]:it)[)i1:(p]]nni)(p[tpp)[p:[p-n::(ut1iin)[n-1-nin]:-u-p-]((i]:p--)1npnt)i:(-]n1]pu-]ittpp(1-pp-[(11i)pu1-:()()uittuu):pui(n(:-nn[(1]1tp)([][]pt)tt1:n[ii1np]]([p[-ut[1n](t]ppt[[)1(i(up]tttt1p):)p)ut)(u([:]-[[[i[nn(nnitiu)1(:[ntti[ti([-up:[iu]]]-pu]1(ii)-npppt-]n((pp)u]p-][:t]ui1ui]]t-[()-)[-:]pnpni-np(p:pp1pt[1i]up11ip]n)u(:(nn-pu)u-uutu]]:n1u1u)p-1[1npppi)u-[[p:n:-(]iu)tp[:u:tun[i:n]p-p:1t][:(u(npnpiin-ttp)]ii:-1:tu]inp(puupn-)1p-p:uuuu[-][([]1np1](1(]]-])ni1pu-(-([p]i:--ip(i[iptu-(-iiiup1))up-pp[-)-)[i1pp-ip1[-up:p1[[n)pi1[1upnup(:nt:t](up][)[:p1tn1pun[:tuni[[[ii(--)u1]p)111pu[[)pp[ni1n1)t::pu-)]:n:n)-(1[[t-]n[p)pp1up)n)p]n[pu]u]u])]-p(i-i[)pnpp[(t)(:[i[(][([p1p(-]1n:-]1[np-n1)[n])uu-in:(n(:p)]-1iup-u-)t]]utt[)][p-:-]u-pt](p[u1-1[:-1:ipi)p[()p(p1)nppt-]:11u-]-it-(pup:p-ti[(1p[ptu-u1n:]--p]:))(pptnu)ip[pi:pt1p[(-iunppu1tn(1)))1((t-]t1]u:ut):1)[tt](ptp-[u[uu(u-ip]-ip]-u]nnu:i-(-p-in:u[()(t:n(ptu)t(n-[:-1iptinip11(t1[u]11][-t]p(t[u)uuttnu-n([-(nun[[u]u)t[iuitn)u-(()pnu)pt-:-]i[u1:uni):ptpt-p()it-pptp-[t::ntpn-p:(1(-(]p)][u-p:n(i)n[up]][-[n[nppn-i(]p1:n1[)ti)p(t--:(u[[))n-t:(:t1ip11pp:)[)t(ut-pun[ui]:((pp]pp)t]-[--p)1:1p[)t(n::u)t:-]:)n:])]([][n)(u1(-)-:]1[(ppt](n1u:t1up)(:[niup[-]pi:u[u[pp:-ut]]:(()i)t1]:p:[-]p-](])1tp]n-p-p)n:i(u1]pp[pn(p]]pnp]pn:ti][npn-t:[::t1()p)-i)]ip]:tu)nt)tpnutp)([(i-p[p[upppt]nn:nu)(it(p]pup]i1[)u)-)()u)n1:in::())1]p1p-i]t[[p]i)1([p]-p(p:i-[utp[:uii-pi-]1[iput[pu]p-t[-u)iiu:p1:1:tinptupi1ip[n((1pn]p(t)111ppptti]tu:pppui-ti1:np(i-[t[1p[(t())p[[t-u)t]puu([p::n:np]tpu[]:u]1pnpt1:u(pp)p)u1]1i)1(n:1-nnpt:])-i[(t[t[[:)[([it)1]:i))t1p][upt[]1-p:pp:[:n]]:[]nt-i])u((pu))t)[1it)ii(1:nt-)u](p::1n[p1:)u:p:()nip(n[[1uu])p)u-piunt[p(]1]pp-t-:i1u:u-pp1tpu]np-:()(:1[p:)]:[npuu]])1i)n1-1:1int-tp:(nu1][i-1t]11[[un1n1[)]pi:t(]uuiu[u-iiut1n:p)(ipn-()n(p(pu)pp1t)niu1n1i(nt(1p]-:1[[ppp-t]ut:p[-[1]np[upin[(u1u(()[]][:t[ppu)([pi1u)p--(][)(]-:)n[t[p1i(:)pi:(pu[tn-pipnptnp(tpp-uiui1p())pu::u:p:uu[u1pt)-1)-)t(ntuit:(-p((-pt-p(i(p]))[(tp1n)]:]p(ip[]p:p1tu]:-1:ti]-i:u]t(:u1)]:i[))1(t)][uupnn-1[uu-pt(pn((---(p[p)t(ip-:pp([u[-n]-):i(unpi1:]p1n:-1ni:uu]pp]-tppp[t]p1p:(n:])u-)p:p-:ppu[p-([)u1(p[uu[i]i][:-:)1[-t-1[u1n11inpptpi(pi)u[]p]ii1(n1[n-n(pn1pinp(iu(p[-]-1:t-(]]np:(p[11)-[-[ipi][pn[]:)(:(u:]tp--]ni):])11(-i[):-[i:1upt-)it()1u:n1[11tni-tu]u1))]p-i[-pn(t)[::1[11tp(1[p-tipn[-p1ppp)n)t-i1[1)):n[p[[pt::[tti):)[)u)---ppni[(:1puiuuu(-(]:p]ut:1-pn)[-t:]--(i[t:[u]ip(:p]:[tt(u:)p([ppnpt(]-1pi1tnitt)pi-)t)ipt]:u:t]])(1p]nup)][iip[pn[u:1)-]n[t-)n[1:i[p-t]))t([1])(it(i[:u1:[]1u:u):[ipt[](ipnu)iu)p:p)]pn()i-pp:n)n(([p:ip-i:t(]pp)utt:p)u-1)(([pup-ppn(]i(p[-)pp-n[pp)11[(-ppp[:ti)p:npp[-]1i-n[]u]pnp):u(])u]pi-u)(ui[]p:p1up-nu-t)uppu(1upp[()n11)](]):]in)-][:p:pppit](i]tp1pppti:p-1i1:nti(t11]pn)n(]:(pp:t:::)p[((1pup1n)upnpt(1pp]:itp-nni()i1p1p]11u(i-npipi[p[t-[-1:1]]]:(:--p([]n--)]i-n[(]::]uuip][:p]-p((-nt-1--][p1:1:11:pp[)nu:(p(p1ni:i(])u:)p():1t-t:pp-[)pnntun](1-[uii-(ttppnp))1i1up[n)p[((-tp:(n1:p:(u]:)1:11[ipi]n([i:t):]1[((-t]1i(:p]-1(puppt[n)]nipiu::-)(tn)-1p)iii1)t:1i][p[-:tu:pt[---:)i)t[-p)-:n)pi)1tp1t:-(nn):)[i(:]u)):iitu-:(i)uutut:-))t[n1][:[p(i:-p-:]piu])pn1n1:npu[p-]((])(11ttn-1][t]1-[upupp:p1)))p-[(pn:p)u-[tp:)(p-tun1-ppp-:[p:-]nnu-:([[:]p:::(n([tu]1p:[i[1]:up]up]-p]]ii-u:[)pt)]p(it()ppp]t)pn[]]ui)u[u[)pu-[pnppnipp[i:ntn]1](:-i[[:pt-)n1i]n(1[-t-n1][(--uu(]n1)]ipn1pip]upu[]1[11u[:u:p(p))1unuu(t:[p11u(]pnu-[-1)(:tptp[]p[tuu][[)1iu[np)(ptn]--pi)1i(nt])pi:)(in)nt)[un[ip]]p([1]u-un-t)(]u()n:tp1[in(ipn[-:1[-1-uu11-ut):p):p(-npp[n1ppu1tip)up[:)inun--it[--uit(-u)u:[(n)::-1:u[)n-ppiupp[-p:1unpu(utu1--ni1ii:]u(pip[(1u:]]]u-t(p1)n1(p:t)pn:))p:(p(p1n:-t((1nn-n-)1(tunip1p[(u[inupnn-p[p1[n[pi(-n(-[1]pp([nip1)[-t1itip)n-pn:n[inpuin]uuu-]1:1-uu(ip][pnp1i[-)[[n(uiu(pi(n(:]t()-ppuu-]))-]un([):(1p11p1nunu1pt:n11upn(n-1[i(:(i]pi:i:11i(i1[1)])p:p:][1:n)tn]]1u[tp]]pp)pp:tpt1)uut(uipu]1)[)1puuiuuu(pu]1n[u]])t1]):)[)])1-i1)1t]npu:)u)1)pi:1([1u(([u[()[:1[p1i])1()tn1pit:1](ptu())](tn-[:pn]uiut()ppi)]u(1i:pip]pnptuuupp1:)i]pn]-pup(p]tt(i1p(-ii1-:-i][p]p-n1)ptn)pnp)]n-)t[n]ti1(uu-:::pin-(ti(1[:]upiu]up[p)uip)tini)t1nun-u)[-]up[(:p:--p)(nn]p(uit[itp-)-1-)1ppiu11([1nu-:t)pp):unt(inp-:npnpp-(]][upi()i[n-:1[-:p))](pip-i((u]n):n-ttt11tip]]nti1-)p]::up:n:n))t-u-ppu-[(pt:ttnn-pu[1[)ti)u(p)n(n[i-nu)i:1(p[()pt-[put-p(]u-]p:n:it[-uiu))]n]pi]n)pp[ipt(t:i))i:np([:]i1)pi]]p[:-)11(::n[ut1tpttu:pp[tuu([1p[(pp:p]:[])[p:puii)ip)pt([[ppn[:t(-(u::(1]:-puiu[i[i[[(p::[pint-u]t]i--[](pi[u-):p[1(up]u1)(pu1]1(:i-n[[pn]1-[:ptn)t[-uu(]tp(p((][pn:]]11:)p11(1p()tu[11i(](n:np)p-uppp]p(p((i(up:][n])i([:)11)1tpuun:-u))-1-ut[:]t)u-i-p:1u1-pntp11n((ppnt(tin1t1ini:()pi[pp]pu-p-ppp(:pt(:)npu]-]-[titn)[unn-(pnnppupnpi-:p[():1pp--]upp::][up1p-n:upnt1iip-)u-([-]]:ui])1--p-n[pt(-:-p)(t-(tp1tip:i)pi(1ppi[1p]i-:1:-[-uptp((11)(uu1[)1(]p1(-p]p-]uupp-nu(])uupp[u]npp[t-in]ttn((1pt-n)]p-])]p(in-:t]iuin)[t[u:nn)tpt-:pin:tp]i1up[ii[tu]([ni-]pnnn()[:ptiiip(]t))t]ppui-1:(:n(pn-t[:i:]t[[[upn(p[p)]tuu1iun]uu:1-ppppp)-pt:(uu(n]]ppt([n-p[n-ip1]u]:p-(-]n1(pu[)[:):tt(1i1(n))([)]1p(p-[)up(-p):p(np])-[1tuun]1[p-pppi]utn)nup-p]-pu]puti(1:[npt):inu-[u:p]:-npi1tp-t1ununu--tp]]n[p1::t1(p)-)((i:p[--tu](p-[np[u((1))]((-ni(-u(1:t1t()un1[(:)--uu[up1p-1pnu]pp1ntiut-]))1(]:-:p[p(]u)(:]u))tppp1-][1tp()un-]p)(]pnpp[-[[i[[u:i1)u)-1-nt-u-u1u(tnpt]([nunp1)ui-(innnt)-1-[[ttt]-(pippn1-)p]11(pi:(]1i([1i)i-:u(n1p)])t-((p)(p-pnupi1n1-pu:pu(p1[]ip]](pninp]11nu:i)-n[pp:pup](n)nunn:[--n(1n:)-in([t))pp]]i--(i1:u)-inniu(]p)n(pn)t-))i]t-u(p:1--t[n[-i[u]-t-ipp1]1]1nupp][[:(tn[it][p([-ppu1p):]ut]p)n-p)i1[upt]1[:]1[-p1i:]]1:uui:pp:-)u1:n(]np)[u-p)]i((i-[iiu((]:]-(p):t[)]u([ti[)]pp1):[:n[up[nttn[:)]1u::-n]up[[[1]t])[):-(uiui-):up(tnpnu(u(]1pupipp))p):tn:)-uu)n[ntp1]p-:]pu1i1t]]pp]uti(-)i--(it[nip:i[(-tn)[]unp-uti-[:[pi-(1up-](]pp-:]npi1it[upu(pp)piuni:un(:ti]1p-(i)u:)p[]u)t(i)in]:[i))uuntppip1(:pu)]:u1]inn:n:i(n1tpi]tupp:ppt]u)1(i[i)u(1pnt[]p:ui]t-n[)]]p)i1-p-(([ppt11np)[inin:](]u)p)1tu)-()n-pppu[[-p-):i-)-1t)(nii)]u(n[pni]]t(p:)-un(nt[t[ip:-:1-npp(niun1][p:(p-]u(tu1ppuu)-i:t-iu(p1pip)])(1n)(un:1((u1-1tpi[-n1)ut:]pu(n1i]p]tup-pu)p1]::(tpii)p11[p)(1pp:p]it)n)]in][u:n()pt--t)p[)[pt1n---itii:[]pn(((uiu-::[n[)1:[ppp-[)p:)p)(p1ptpu1i]u)u(i(]uu1nt]:ti-)(1pp1t-i:1(1-p]upu1p1(]p:)[[u](p1n:pi)nn]n[pn)((i-(pi(i:ii1:]tip1)]n1i[:t[1i:ni11niin(-nui:-p]t1(]p(ii[[i1n:ttpip]([p)u]:]1[p(p(i(tn1pn]]iut)pt]-i-]t)ntp)-)ptppi--]-)[pt][p(1p(p])(p:1]nn[u(:(pi-p:[[-np[)])pnuut1]i()ii[uniitpnunp:)u)uni:np-)p-]nn[u]((1up-nnt)n))pp):-:tnu11](t[])nu1:tnp(1-]:pt(-p(u[u-nuu[[1)pp1:(tt)pun-[u[n::-)(1:un(nput[(t([[tn[-]-n[)ntnt1))ipi)):ntt1n[pp1up]tpt:)piiti:-p(i1-p1nppt11([ut1:itttn][t](]pin]u])ipp-p:ttnti-((tn1pp:ut(iin)1u)n[:[(1-p-upn-(n(p1[-ip-[:pn-]u1nn:p]-::n:)11[::np:[u-::1it[npp1t1ii)tpp1:(tpp:[:1-[:ti)(p-in[ui-n[p1-)[)pn:t[:tu-:pup1t[:i::p]pp-]t[::(unp]])p(n:][:ni)])ipnp[]un]t-1])u[1:ut]u]i)pippp:])[1----nn]ui(1ui1n1tp-ni1[pn:]-]:t]p1pittiuu1[[uu)n11pipn-n[:tin-t-([p(]u)-:1:n(t[nupi:)p-t:::[u:u]:i)-1[]up[iu]tpiu-u1[:[i]u:(tu]:p[i[tpp)):])[u)ipp-[pupnn]p-p)(--p:ut:u-)npp1)[((]]t)u)1un1(t:-t]())u:up][ip]n)in):pin1t:)t1n[n:[utpit::pp:ti]p--1[pupupuuu(-[n([puut)piit[[n)n1n)1i):t)ui(tp-:()n1t]i1i]p:in(n1[p[(nnp)n1):pnpt][]-i)(tuu1p(pu):[-u:ttp()u[n]puipn][)1(tp]-pi)iu1n1[np1t:tu)1:1u]pu)][u]ppp-p-1p)iii()t
```

Good luck! A single slice will suffice.

Comment: This produces error which is not allowed. (unsliced)

Comment: This is invalid as the unsliced code must be syntactically valid though it does not have to do anything and may not take input.

Comment: Missed that, fixed

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242651/84290)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 784 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242638/110555)

```python
"""Dntii(():n1n]ron):1i(]n)-(::n~rutnp1:p:l1('pn:np(-()n[i[t(r-:t~::rtn:p n1lp1::1]]ippy]iri(1[)1pi]noi)r[):)]epipnu:[tpp((:n~n:n ))s(1peu)pa-pwt[nr:nn+ru:)ii]itu
ii1([)1)sp(:tu-li(+)(thi
sn(rdp]1nit tuatt:aip:p]ntiu(turerp[pnthat[](1r]iip+:i(lii(p.upu1eesp[ne
:np]rait upn:u:in)
eutwpt
t:1dn(iir(opt(1s]tat+irert[i()esi1:rink)p(r1:.pn(r[]etnntt:sple:-idnt)[pp(un(ini?p1n:
(enpit)1 ei[ir(t((snup=i:np:[iei+u((=i)ttnnriu)(tn=ti[tn[w[tp:n)=ntnpnu.(pi
u:=+t::-tt:nnn(]=n)pi(
u[1trep>pn(s:uots:]nn prrtptd]
pupupprpnapt1iptrtrn)pr]ns[:[r(pii::inr.:isp[)nnnu~e(sitpplnt1((
nn
e~:[ei(aspsu(sp+p(:-i[l[:)t iitn]pn(:et[rs[(nt)tp:n(rnpapttra(u[n:ptt n-eiunt(nts~(stsi(]u(psripnyntpirp)]p:ti(stnnprp[tuenii nurepl:ti(r1ptpi)(1a-(:nn(-rip](1t1t
rtt1oinp:11]tntrnup)r]ni:)(n)([]mpn[:is 1t([ppi"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZPBihwxDETv/RXNXiLT9IDITTDJJYf8QQ7Gh4YxrEinWsgyy17m1yfas@VyvSrZPuP9wvfX6@3t7RdClagIGM0vFGGlhrKTCJ4@A8ZicjJ9MwiMdiqoWoN8l3iKeEBsBZ85J9yamn02dSWuhU0bLi1ei5TWTQ1TapgRpXjKraUMYuuz2LHbR1S4AJtPKapNYy6qTClUhpHE3E@lrVC86zJA/rDG0FhjHhFyqIm15JkU07tbNcT7EbURe1O1TZTOpLXbtMm9D6voS0I1P1JlJuAURVn6jA@LJYQfIFWny4J4tDhi01SOqlT6UBZX/C1GznKzNFRbDyC9DDu77PpAlJq4M2WgP40hC3WYRuG1a03pIBqYdtf0IVW7bpPoriVSyHUmLO6ReaN@ZHKCckd2gnkj02XKfQuRPV8EQO2OYkrLrBze7UdaGjKvGNKA1dzD4tEWS3wzNxwWrBYenve8YVSpnroqGYPfRDOhksLz2Wlo9nYimGgBlv6U2pWOYWPSsC3r2bWeVUqsqoGWb0uP6qNShvDlnByWL4YfNGsuTcSKvetE5MR40oiRqzfJhueifCJM3UozCc0zIB3XmB2qK7JfO78OnC3nCvGRG5sR7Hk3@w6OxSP40kyVuQWScVpJSJVCKFTbP0NNxJWDsiPNz/B6/e7nea1/Lj8f/wE)

Only needs one slice

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242638/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 47 bytes, 1 slice, [cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242618/slice-the-source-code-robbers/242648#242648)

```
»β₀₇⁽sßḋ∪₁ĿɖC↵‡_Ẋ$ƛµ"√₀tṠ⟇¤H∧+(Ȧfꜝ⁼∑↵dTḋI∷›»kpτ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu86y4oKA4oKH4oG9c8Of4biL4oiq4oKBxL/JlkPihrXigKFf4bqKJMabwrVcIuKImuKCgHThuaDin4cwSOKIpysoyKZm6pyd4oG84oiR4oa1ZFThuItJ4oi34oC6wrtrcM+EIiwiIiwiWzEsMiwgM10iXQ==)

A bit harder.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242648/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 233 bytes, safe.

```
`NZɾ√√₁₆₂‛‛ẋȯWġ₴ẏ.tṗṫ⟩εpj*5;[[kromer]]ȮGβŻ∇QQ↳ꜝ^QJ∧A⇩≬[pipis]fWPėX℅dżT←›Ṗ‡[[BIG SHOT]]!ṗȯḃ•I[[classic vyxal jankness]]Ẋėṅ⋏HðβėEV3RY BUDDY 'S FAVORITE [[Number 1 Rated Salesman1997]] ṁẏ℅□ṁQḃ₌ŻKKQTẇλε λ½ no ₃≠ Ḣ¥s in λλ square ʀ¬ of 2`
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgTlrJvuKImuKImuKCgeKChuKCguKAm+KAm+G6i8ivV8Sh4oK04bqPLnThuZfhuavin6nOtXBqKjU7W1trcm9tZXJdXciuR86yxbviiIdRUeKGs+qcnV5RSuKIp0Hih6niiaxbcGlwaXNdZldQxJdY4oSFZMW8VOKGkOKAuuG5luKAoVtbQklHIFNIT1RdXSHhuZfIr+G4g+KAoklbW2NsYXNzaWMgdnl4YWwgamFua25lc3NdXeG6isSX4bmF4ouPSMOwzrLEl0VWM1JZIEJVRERZICdTIEZBVk9SSVRFIFtbTnVtYmVyIDEgUmF0ZWQgU2FsZXNtYW4xOTk3XV0g4bmB4bqP4oSF4pah4bmBUeG4g+KCjMW7S0tRVOG6h867zrUgzrvCvSBubyDigoPiiaAg4biiwqVzIGluIM67zrsgc3F1YXJlIMqAwqwgb2YgMmAiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Maybe if I add enough deltarune references Lyxal will get distracted...

The solution was simply `Ṗt` - of all permutations, get the last. `[72:18:-1]` I think. Idk what the score is.

Comment: How many slices?

Comment: @lyxal A single one will suffice, as with all of them

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 9999 bytes; [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242691/84290) by [AnttiP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84290/anttip)

```python
#i:i(n inb(rnu()[ rl9:or iup)iixc a[-a[it"x.:)tsuiam:rp):)=)):-p)[nuaoininiena:n[i ) x):i)[]ruixp]o)
#a * e)[aptppp[:":"(toi(nip"=:ntioii;p"([(nn]u0.::)f:i(1:(;i) rb)8pf)eip:1iriie1nri-]p](]ri[( 0)"[a*
#  bx:l)enindf(i=ne(6ut.icuc(1i:c[iiptp 19x(]0tin"p1i:pnn*(9e"=di~ex;iupre= i)i9f n;8*aan,pp1:1io ):
#i4ni2fo,fpi )ot: t=-iu)ete:=i(iuu t)nn:"r 1bp]ii)i1(*r)nnf])i([mi-n:i.i*o:n;]silrifi1d ri[arjn"*p()
#u"9iipx=nupuli8l*tc"  e:a-.)rrarni,i[)ptpoit:spi:uax,n9ni)ppedf~: [tpnn [nut lo st()pf"t   n=0=1iar
#pa:ntau(n :ixenn]()atenu9(tn((::pin ffe2r:a(r *i ( 1)ien ae=pma:xt ( ntoi[b:a:f)=ri aa:=i;t:p*,::"9
#ut0 nmcn"afsnnf:+pttre:i(8(an[iipc-=)([~]n;));;:(rb f1u)torrp"rxc1 (]nlp(ite)p"=n[crry:urnt= *i"rnd
#,)i(ip= :)i,f)in(tn-u;rcner(,x 2it (]irp f( ,")eii)ian: (xc=)trt;]s: tiiufn((p psp~ n*unu"n(]tpota(
#r)r:p1,sirn((taoir;n1)l=rn[(9[*(1:n ))()9~i; p*)ani)uri"]i:i"]i;()(:a):=)([ar(o:]in ["i-)]iu](idet 
#n("rp ]at:]abu xpia tfoi[a"fse*ta4apnet"pb)=, ie*(dup]un9)u*1nop*r;t(cp.~(r1id*et0"innb pcxi:*(.in(
#)t1e)ean*"i *f]"l)=nnf:=t:)*(t6i"nt;+u=t)t):e"]"11"" nio;p9i)s=n)p:"fei n)nce(p:tcr)(ti))ianrt)-=)*
#ein)is]eni;(t=(- i)]ipi(rt~u:1]1p)2arigiai:xn,xe~(u(: =*tif1 :)(i)in8r[ ip(a;:"t()*(inx*;"arei([:ri
#tuft" ii0")t16 : pit)9+r1nrn);ry"n9 (, ftt:tn*uinn b].~a m": ir([)i(e"noet]]1nnriinftapt*onn((o:[ip
#pip)t)p1"[i 9bm"e=(; ]ti(a;:]]=): )[)im nnxgu)r:r:ntio,[*:pre"oir*]:pu:(r( ]ox:0et :)n:n.t[,nuta)ip
#tpit:]ay  [niini;[o[,n(si(fin(ppi)(p:*op (+ie " )=a)=nni=9:enofta:ui(rt+ )[nt" n-fe2o8=t(p[[:];x . 
#===rrii[ )f); "cip:=n=t)b[:"ip"((rrnopt (tynt(:rp*9mu ]x.o;t(n+ f(eitdfrx[pr )*yp] i(nid* ap8]"(p][
#;"p)mpp0t :if;rmiu1*e:of(: trr* *ia)i[ nx]ni)n()ten=exnt;if]((2ia:]iprmi:u"nf8tn;-pt "[n*p*s"pt":m:
#ilr.pxc(]paa(o"((ii= )t*pyri(;;a4ut8p)n(=:= ()t(ptx1n"n(f( (a)"")1:+)id"ni 1pu;n*ippli:]r):ey-i4x=)
#((;tp1 i"ntnpni ) "[a(tp: )((n[t xtn*it=):ieai(rii"]:d: u(a:)o(epu)1ter e:*e[cecu"(itip[( i)]n"ui(i
#;i:(iii=ia"lap+e[)n(ir itt[ uitii r(u1x3)ra[ irtt~;=~n1+o:nri:a:t.n"e oaur2i at*r[]~punnp" )1 lia"t
#r,e])iut(9p";ub8tr:"8il ni=e)*tt]en:n:fi"i*b(snti[(a:i) inu(xoit")yrprnnis*))"otini")t]ni1epm;nr:r"
#lc2ppr(tirtep"iine9(:o=pt=]=u[p f:ippntn9u))e u [o:e:)a= [*tn[ u(ipypt: t(ii):n u(t))tepr*e")an(p+"
#a:b.:eel )"(ln))ria"tr[ttdan((:([*1:[i:ut=*-:(*[l"(]ii((piir1(nit"1tu[))(o)=bi=i:ri(;f)i (; s(taint
#)[o (du::i ( iu[]lp)(tut("oxirxn:].*(=a)i inb:m(op= (ini:-tp:i: pt[:s(ut(ii.,tir)rufain]p][(an[)it:
#iirx=:ri(:ini)(u)":()]]ril    0prefp1in[(iptiiid"f"be"un))nu[9(p*t8p rrirn( i)]i)]f)t(n(n2)o(x"t"(t
#ifti:au ifdi itnt p+ -pfin;p(  aoi:u]ppoc(t:p ([l-reatt([ua)pnsn(t)u,n"ros9r]tn"pn(;x;(i[1np("iypps
#*:p+(bipnte((i(pp]2tiex=rot,iini, -i(yp:ttn:[([ x,(ip n9:;-n]tn0*eoi"(nf)(u"p(rpapntip"fi8)("=rpn1)
#(tu(])(-)ci)iffi:*in* );9=i":nopin ;(entue.i()p)="rm;::t:u[(yi+toi))  *brf[nn8   ))nxpno a"u ;)cr =
#p" n(imt8"rir[:i*o]: )id"(iu~]a r"f1n(u"vtnldx(:nii) bir;p)t()ysux:pratnpnpfnnu(=te  (p81d")o(mt":1
#]n pi-t( )ouoer(tnx:0tu.)ti*(:tn)a*f) )p1iil,:(ray: 1+)inm]uiii=(s)tii*tdnnp[*m(:xit[( ":erut"rnei*
#):f)[ifu**"i):tt(n9i tndn* iu,xnrm=  (uorp**p[ ta[1n; a*"ef b"pn)np) oro9(tti)tir)( 9p"p=(pnuo:nxia
#: uin:lii[iinra(:"ei* ii,nt"),i"rep8nui[:"ppoiit-  )(*tn "b" iti*aa)*p2nf*)r)iinun:))dn 9i(t=(~mist
#o tn=ic pr]p)1ptiiai:[ i):))  ; it9itu) [9bipiub(a:t)is-i:9a-iaimuip)aipdi)it"[uu)*+n)()f[=t(r("]nr
#)uyu;i[(;8n (y;i1::[ai):o()8*vpuo*)i ri-(pnn-]ua+:.(x~trn~)nnra(i)"fuuix.-*"xe 8)n=:)u tn*:todfrie]
#):0nf):rrtp",yipga "pa(tt:pptr1p *i((up"t riau:")b"n i=(]d:e-s[)if(xi)n" [t(mc*i1[picne i)ci]o* ii)
#( in":)futir)t)i;;:[,()u(1utiuo2i;ttxfuen:)"iotftx:s y]].d,+iy1nnu p:+bu m1:"ft:=";pp))g]"mft tra-t
#r[i"a[="r)iuntbiit:ote(p)bi  :]ic[("1 =[t~1et*nsni((;xu()]:p[(-;ie*t"nn:pi  ]ot"*ce[[iipntr)(0tm::(
#=t pu:)ir)up1n[)i)i=nf ["i) *bn( tiapi;pni:i): [)a) ::n9o0[n[(tp8:y.9;pi~t);11upoc:ia;x1,n4efen[:;t
#n)p;rtin:n=ni*i"1i:etai rm1ftn;nu80*ti(i(f"t:r0oinr)n ixort:[sur1ru tp] asn"i)tpte" 1n n:ton(0erua 
# d[tr*intrii ~.:ic)n:a:iip-~n*[[p(=xnaofi[t ="u(t,frnri(nie;)bctcn pvi"nn np~x=)tu]a+i rd]cenuriia.
#i)uup;s:()*a(unp](t)i-)[tus*)p(::(nput0n]:r"(]ni**rrmrt:(r8 ir)unp*.[[nruepi:-p1ii(0i:*:r a;b=ria):
#,(:t[ fiar;n(t, u(p[x=0"n"[a=("=uo**nt":p:(f-n::li([:ii:[i"binnpp([n u:xp p:)(u))[ (e;=nnin) pi]uu"
#[)y(n" io;oi*);it(d]r]=x:xinii p("))=mnil:a:e:(o")p=it [p[tfpprx:nisux=po:n"a*u )()rr)i~fonp)tper;[
#tr(:b():sri =s~r)),tmc)up*:trtif)nr:itfiu]nn r p:,)iiyr ryu]i)]n)= b(]i)uc e[*i.as)[i"n,u,ric)prnx(
#"(:"i9-ii(:tp=i(s=rnfeeyiu:nl=r*m"1i -u"i]t;ppl p] u~itu)"n (*rinir("i(*r~ (9m(:-"r:)(rin)1il]tx8n(
#"nrtnn(ii+n:~ p. trtts(i )="i9*c[ii upn[1nlinirru"e:o(r:";ud* r( f irsmpnpnp*e:nrn)*i()oa["1i;=:)]"
#1t(=i)*r[;fpu)t(j9:191mu utnyp=s:oi;psmn p,]=rr ng:-i( t*r~)(paii(miii(t)nn:e,upu ::r:i:toi(no)iyir
#it(i;:rfi*)ir*(tpy(1t(]:t d ]:tnpiy)*r "n)e(et)tno x)9) ))in0([(=;endiou1un]= ifai)i i;1at(8i=ttn:i
#3px (it rn[1n"nd))pnt~up1prine0[p)]]o)du*; r(i)i*((u:(e)( = nn)(; :n(eii=n)r]aoni))a1(+e(if(tti tt)
#innrp:(i:1)ufr;i"())u],teepa[:1i)1:)ir"u(nnx8*1;ifrie(o(pitsu:r:xrupitnn::pi((f;"ipe*):]id i[rr1ee=
#;u"):,:) =)i)=i(9)-1:*fnpip :t]2") )t.cai:;trnnpt) [iio;8i-:(i]=i]ti1su~t((1raii i:ei().optphn*n9:"
#u(if):"f[nne(8et;a":6)([)uo(atnso*]lr4~t)dnii(*f in()*]1n. )(]mt(1i(e(:imi =(t)p   *[;"8]:p(fntpdp 
#["i;i;xii)*anfiii"rir:8p "itpe"pf d"]=pf=t[t,8]i(i: d::"tr(-(tnuu+:m]i )r:ia(*:ii]:ni1;e* ))in(urn:
#  1abl )(tp: ,i[c)*["ditne)=rti;nfcnet)npra1 )i ii(r pn )[tpan )tt:t,a:itado1(=n(:(i*s8pr:iir n*(p-
#1)";9=4rt; 1t)lf,)pi-i:l(en)()up:(nn*piui(;n:e(8r" (nn;indp(ic)epn*n:i]8d= "gr(afpt](+tu:rn)("]tcup
#a ()u"j(nr"dxpxa[t)nr a[o:,);ii)aiuc)it)e)"rbti[(i"]"ppi)tnpi*(eii]ru2](u  u(p)=i):8=tniipun)pia[tj
#pnb.im*t)pr);;nini:int)(upu"oni"4p)tf:))(n i8r)~pp irni(ii*o(=nrpur)]nart9)tap+u:=-"l=fti*;tna.~(~u
#fuf(i- ]1nritl "i[c."*1 s((l-e(a) ee":nftcip:orr ue-au(ept e.-"nn(eeolni(np9t=i(nrtnnn":u)"mn-ei:np
#c(a  r(i*r)ii,i i[1)t"l "tr( 1) )) *)nmtuo))[t"]()t1ant:*["dnp[m(u[8"[,u=p)2t)c=itin-f"tlns:ipn8)] 
#9(i[xi uia:*(e(9=)o) a" a"(e[p* :nmii-tnni*~a):*p*)::)" ttexait9x"x(sent;p:u=]n eunf:iup f;init9lof
#"nn=;i,rai)nftinituaifpr:i e0pr"p)s =;"*xt((1( m nxei"annn")ie a(np-r(( frx[ bra0xii( ir:1x:t(aun"i
#tnu];e ]expeiu9)*)*r=a((p;)n"n;8.txi]ir*i)aix)[ysn rpp]+it)rnc": i[=piipi n::t)t0t] i8ptp"x=eupi*" 
#"nprrati+t)p8):xpr0b1 ,asn )t8: eiir-u");"i]o]tun)rrrii9t(x"r):oixnius(b *t]n)oi  i)i(c; ts"1: reii
#t pt8n)-*us8pifrp):9istne"1pri))](pii:i[n i):8 :,a]:tn"1(=nire,])x]pnn[[it[i"]ii; )pp n"ttic:)(i n"
#ipt)l+finn: 8 ir8pp:1)r*i):)"aca,[ n;nn[u:e(uiioi :,:"cmo(tai:ni*);xde*.f)([nprp]a=p*b)8( i;.):ta:i
#);(:)t:[xs( n0i io[l()u"i-i""a)+=nt))r(=r(ti 1rni)12 f=inilntuun:l; *-(]rx;s*()iir[=*"pbi*fdn*:*(pn
#ns0"-p0i n(utdue=:nri8t(t:m=)[t[x=rrrp(=+pp:,epsn"o(ou;ao"~*dx1))lit]i( ]a")"to]i"pnrrxratptpnieais
# iro[tfipti[;((t[(en)1rnrp"(i( o((ign:it=pu*(ta*)ie"~) t:)) :*t")i-1p tifpl"ni[=fi=:)irn, i8xricupt
#1*iii n:ner rp*)b]:)uit[1:i"ni) rntfn"i)"p =eint[)r=n;:nryp:8 t *ulsi-pl*i=;":enn-i[ptuait e[oltipn
#i()pa~ia)y"i:([(i]t i up9"ti:(ren:oia):aa)pte1(t n-u1*==px)"a"no)(rn(un]2iac-x ]opu("8cpit(ibpi"nr(
#un:n =ppt))peri;r a )t) i)c9")c"p"ei~aip,(:"r)(o))+nrin=tn::=-ie (-"ionfne tee)(*ni) ([pp(exit) [r)
#re"e"]-n )na)nnuil)i(x1a[(,nr)iceu (= -p8t f u"a:re;1]n*~d)2=i)(n( :)9m*))pnirn)u:i (anitii "tn:i[u
# :ri:ro=( i"n:p:~*inrn)uuu(px:ra:]:(8ne+t:trfi n -)i)* ir+nei1 as"=;i[=i()((::py:[:(]8pi"-p:tsr]t,c
#" pui*;r[xbi8ia)uan8o(*:ai"a"f(*d((1ii(pnp i):"s:p:i() :*tn*n[itnrii:] xf*9rc9ai)n"]"u*[nii](n1sn)(
#: aai1)i)yi ,in):)nun):(": )rieip p)r(r fi=pa-:p[te"*dptep)ni)i:(ini)rti,u t=auoba):ppn1tn" n[(* u"
#at(risibplnpp)*t(:9rtnr*]u:lt]=]ieu]):" [" dri)tpsxp+:]en0]buair;n;(sn:(prp(=p"uij;o[))  :et:ni;py9
#nn::p*[=i)(ta(ie:]]t i"dpip(in1 ]i[ts t)pni((-;nt i  t( t*(:)pop)i if0-bp="14](r("prrp;:];:())(fps*
#pputu)=n*efir.n]i[:)r ,pain:ip9 ty ui (x;i[fs p(non]i-f ):n;t]nnru"isoopeli(:[bt]i*]1( f umixt)1i[t
#iurp"9 )uui[er9;(ttiu(r)( i8fnt4n;poii tm1)nce:9) :)tn"n[ue*r"p-8i m=p9r 0u(nt)t)t)t9[e"*)i,ef"pf(*
# :p=r)[ (n[i[h)n]pe(txm )b:t(ut::ti m;::p(rt (*flinn :np-i)="p(p(i("]n(*tcmi;pn=c)t:ai1]idi"~8p:[:i
#(:=ifrc)pp)"mui()i  .nt1ri*;r(eui":i(t)i:[)"r[ri)i()f=""n(p*(:i;n(2(:n;4a"(h[pu" :o([(; 9 ut]ifpttb
#(((=:(p=ioo"(r"=ynn*[i]n unry tppa[a1:cinp;(t;tenpion=o(pp;o-tp:nt)nx(n a]:t:r1 y)(nst(nr*nalx)e:*m
#in:rpt".:fptp]n[t(""iif );d"""0 :a :t(is((e""*+"int:e)~ p8"[nab:pt:[aneirn]in,: 1i[uienb6(1m(utt()(
#t)p(ha=[ "t;p)*fn)imp e =  )i 9(*p(]*r"i2 :1u[[;;rn=t(  (ar"n1]:"i1nrvppppan[,][[a""*pn y )*tr) rni
#n) ipintbre, (r)ny;",reei[i:iyn n*](r(r1xit1()p)[) (  ([ ppn: t=iri ""]([s= nr:9rar)*i):toir );n: =
#p[p(ii,(tpi : na+()rmrnl:bi:)aurr[n ptnc :-f4-. *it)sf ]ip:iiou**(:insr:utxm()ni[piri) i)pn]inr()t:
#(pinuen (1)xnb(on" ))f"  impi*9;1xpa[oeni[]:p):*("(1n(i:it;:(0iionx[;i*ri=uuiinl t:a((xa+ip)0upi  (
#:]"u" [ (to[:i(frn-:pt)i([pe"so~*pr tmt"(tp[nd(*90if" pt"ipb:an:*u:=auehn8-:)8)~ti;it:ari((epr:i 8,
#:8[[a li:+9"n)"rt;xatp:(fiue)]in[ppioe:it(n)-a;=i=)fie (("t"n[n)]))*:p"s(i(1:nt*pn: ra(pino=(4-arii
#iiyt:(o;d  ]l:(tipe:itn"*peie1*",t"*np,n=2]niin:(fa(;ni]ii"n:p(o;ivi[x(.:=npco"*ns)"u(]iu)eip:i(iii
#i=atpni(aat.tietpit:p)frp9;piapinri*oi=]:(nt)1ta:i r1;iiyn u ifxnin]r=nntnnan-iii: sir)ppp)8iy((d()
#)rn:d ~x8(;)"np)f(:)rrfie * led[npiit*"x("nu:)i )~9iny":igtrtutit(p1:pp:n)()pp" 1l:=ai)o1(i+)ati:*:
#(nntuo"rnpirt (:c t;)"r;(9i;1"n*"(;t" x;:[ r")n(ai)o]+)t(in ut)):1i*nnr n=is)=":"rt) dori)t(ne=o)")
#i 9ou"  pi88[:pcrpndtlntocr]in":8n*i=:e;nipeiapaiocn"6fi *ef"pra*9."e( i))innt0a(n)atp":neinsi=ni):
#fnitae )[  xiooppui1ixtl][i"i.n,i:tir"r.uttxtau;:+:n=a)t=iu=aod "u1=i()nc:ur  iit~eptit:ne"(t-ani9u
#if:(u:pn(o];t3o[(-())t,p;(p]d=d]u[=deti(([:]ror:a"rpnff0:n(b)()i( :c,(;*;(ninii)ixit)d)"o frilxen)y
# prn1 fa1 "[(( noi1pn)n)unetn=r==fpaotp.i)uc0 i)ni)(=1]i=iyue1 op(;)bt"i))]8i(:i(;:a"t=)+(:r*d,uin=
#ine::e)p  p= s"e]( er"ris] :io;*=)ieiippno(upi(i)n)pi"p"]npi-u s]c*s: ma "":p,"n"))(a (tp]incf+i o)
#(srup(9]us" ti:"[=a;:f)eu9:uo ai+i((uipiii u:)tare"+ nr2)-nc2n:r(rupi))]ia(.(l"8) :::(=it();i::=ir)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HVrbrhupEn3PVyDyUuCLdu8TjWxafAniAdt0pkZ2NaJh1H7xr89ZZDJKdhy7G6pq3WiXd/t7lf/9999PdkyiWG5UpZMJqj6vbq2KezHM@12lcEqBm97PzrStc3q5Wowz3hh3KiZITysLfmVJTgIro3bj2IRYO@8lrubHz6Ssyiak0kopwWmnqa24LxftnTRemeeiKZBI7F9n58yCZU2OZjaq3sylLCZzcRNX5jxJ5VMskWLlQOrL6JDsj59K3Xb3NBlreSzEXjL91duZ7/1OE7t7YMb91XTdKX41Fl3wahGxdM3aP/iT9xm7rtkrNnxdlMwXm5IcS5lw51UZ9@Mn/xL@XtbjUrDRtTnV/Im7yS07z8S9q2ZEnK5qupXIuNBEtuKlJRqm8OKTOD6zXZ3MceNn5YWnh8JGUv1HtC2EcnV9xVp3L730J1@ett21Utml09nUmqrwkYPBZlZubivsetqPchU2peTH8nEqNGxMoTdNPVe1NTJl0U0pJf7LT5zqj58F3Wqpo/mO94zCk0ktS79SEyLnCotalvxdXaKqLCtSk0GTVcq@vJLbG14RtDHcXHKL8ZVVSqjC3FyxR@f0FTtpX0ped9Fp2VADdyit1YzeXijJaMj95A2FT5TZmHl2VG9qmbppa61F1/0@KYryLMQtGwyLhHutb9erNI816SqPHz@PqCwXr5zh42JYsIFTn@tdcqXjrr4ZK41ci1pIHTUGCV1J4hTtd29abWgE@sjcF2y8qLKVjxLbpWuhiCK3RD9@VlNdmY4bV7ypYeTrLJN5@iqBrsFiWEUZQ@b64VkVaxK60SvrCIDht5kMuWTc2G2qtLqI8gbNJxO5R@JHburHTyGNZcbUXEy3rvbCSbUFJU562bJt6VcqkpsuN@OPirOlRy@xy9V0O8labJ0b3cv5Q3Xih83tS7PITZX7zs7SGbX58dO0KZucxGpWdon6afxojW/OWGp/sZY2H7pvphmXddTTpLUSXudyZbN5McXpJbMSI/dMxbV7NdTYjKLWZtBQgDGzGN4iwDhT83QCpCIXpto@3U1xKuY7Vf7Nid0uxz1/qJNT3jZeJjSS0CK51KC4UJqdxgBbYtntrFPNAJKr/ONn60vTivlLY09/KacKN3M9VBCEmLm@tVwVHdXSmmtoKEqhbvH8SeqlneJKAYOTtay5xTgJWIVlaSApuwqavLrABTjhgkqUSYParreXzp5mFRuPdcXojVMG13kpkf13x5DUP4R2DNaBSjTmxEZXOiabVFx394VGOyNOzi0cgc9kxk0aVo6evxUwi1XwHFb8K21MC3pWChsU2q5F0YGz0sr4NLrG/uqyrFi066O2B6xFUBI5AbjrxTcqIbg47@qM6fLeV@wxKLOYWek7CNUL@nwDI4OJiWrFDAEs7S2NwPL2@uoq7ucVUyUHwCdzeyx1D6UqY98lqsHhD6tSuURNJYYfP2ddzKuUL@ySl7m@uE82u3VBd1utFqDFjoOSPQIgQgaU4/OOkeMlEn1zAjIKPuaAvuXSZD5hRTqILXbTpWn3Giz8rOey3ymWlGjFypm9Ms2Wd2Wa5/Srt0vB1b3zCreg0vZJgGYQACWjtZncwfBDC6up9Fksl/JkFysm/n3iX7sHCxPNrUxq4EGKDF2DzlAraDiRhKZ2DBU3TADnhOozcO4eTnVKzqyUSzdTyxW8bXO453vXYDEuUCxgQTQahhGe2WHx7DnpZyqHHLBqhvq2FlTH21lV6tP@P1MTwFBb@8z@I9MB@lEZvNvOorNaU6/foN9ma4if0kUKZmRST1y2gbuOGerTG12Lnvvt0qrTF34C1D4b2xpg6sQtrNneaMP4BmwBystwBDs0Rpt3LRXjtllj9ArtZCAODZxyec2Cmdc/fj7v36VUEEFtuWgMcb6SW31pPvoeQL4ORUYpr92YrLoKq8vOJK@CbYLNgsLfZQgq6mFApp2awXSUarMGm1I54CbJ3c4u56cymp5iTB0brKG1RxqiRcFOQK3rzduTIxueGszPYHXmOmFWm55aD@Dp1fgbqu7GvEAzFDC9gdZZUC4TVgVidW5oHvcQnwUEh/Lpdee6i4tnSwAgD9vkXrRCe0BO7E4YDgYLteA26mMj5yPqYWpfcGU4ljBUzwDqGGFcyY/bO3zSUDfakYlwNE@otPoCdyzwJxAXmBYMyEMv@pZ1x56lhysViwlXgDPk6A@3mrhg0IXkG7O36waHhZssDUPSFS8PLLZJU@WgTgWcMhdSCirmeixlvRM0W1F4nmpOrVHoyRTZoKSmH0XXdbvW2OCYhOZ9Jg6TFNL8LmX78RNEd6Abo7cZQARZxe/Gefd1bcfBZUd1YnpDJ5q4QEHtR@xJydXNJ8FFv2xeWZMsKIIuVAskDjDRC18MaV8LZBZgbJ2ioZO5QxmWBWrGYpWZr561A2tBTWfK0no@M8yO8bq@Zuea64HefIBNMUYpe6tLELmgwqjjXmRVSXc1m3tVHlQP5iR@tYtGXYODS4sAO2oPY/eJSVW9TIJV/tvk@djJgaqNusEJQCHIvLe@g/PTYIuyCLDjW1aKymV6aDTlBfKafvyMApk6NYJ97CscShOIQutn09gSdMokuxgFwWF@HiEb6e3UBLaSV@yDKWjDO9m2B0Ae7Ivczg2col2uvcEQZYb8GhiywEu3EHmDypNcWTV5oGbcj7vUl8fK@gqOtyWoltDRWSWr86JuaLORYtRaV5hBKPuYYVIgj@KpSAf37Jx@/ATVsbgnFAVtromcxr0hx0dIkDnCnOVykc5QF4wYczuh6gSwK32DamO7KRlbvmWxpiJrSBdnzEPUlYdl@Lx4wwivWLbnuyo1FjMNLMAygAqRQNDQGde5cutGhStGkPsNzNXgPE7srumE97469DtxeWBumg69G3sQ@LQlQB0r6Sjwwqa/@wzWmy@i6D3z5FxIuMVK5mL/LX21ADtCB3Yvp9jTwZ1p/7QqHzh77JyNXjrSzvlk9Z7VxYh3BlFArGsrFJNzHD35wpC7WlvRxzeX30npAkEB9EqrU4E0EvUCmw5W606bm0Yw8xQfLp820MZCOyRTw9zT6255CoXhcVGKO8d1FH7gBJykEZ/66BkKAU8djmQ6TXilr99w521fOgjfaF7b0na3qXeM58fxwG@YoK6KO8B7via4vOa8nksx5nfUr6VBwdNp6ElgnQIgBlGRdkNr3QrwF3NjpaDf90B6Uj60z5SbBY9gY/OOdAknFOg0w7g2jZSEDAVP1LS95zDCgDTM2Vd7OQeb6kFWHZa@ml6mwZoGkW4ZntkAx2C9xqkgNoJ30SkVTDLKObmuXwGs2crFvc/XufCnmXmaOkjOcZr36Si/8pIluBk7gZmdK/TMiRdGnkAizFABVV/TAu8h/fIFSwpWQ3py9QtBF1lO8b7W5sLW61TRZfigtAnW1UrLWk2iBG0X@gIiE3yXeoRWwVcNFkF9zo7v8H8QWC6nj9gQCvld0rowPIXX0L3jUqHukKs8m9u93cEY/8KG4LrlA2vSekwHrPER78hruGg6g@pN72XeICI2URekY3T/ZELrEO2CPEdSkMYkQqwRqdjaWl/YBdWLGjWWYs8hSO0ZefI02Ie@wLKuqjTfkO3SSL9HEFRQC/LjDG04QqNL2P2XFjgjD7IGUCzA74qjBUEX3ACnzsAr6xvcdykUIOxuR8hyQ/NMUJTnYWTFgBVj79D4YN6EKUfgWNmamRs9Yo1@B9GBcBWExxj/En6ihtnB/pniEfFCCW2BA9lBy2BiX0BTOtkOzkFoNvxZVpBaK7nOsKmtkruRcRtSq98@1Zhje90xakAsBmIxcDXcFmQzlL1iuQiZ/K6qvvvQWjFe3WAtTL@rHCyf0wa@1XLsx4r2wiztGGENSuTrCaV0DWukDWlxyfnN3QmSo31h3tSpa44NKHsqDFL/DDYD8MlWbBcExfjpo@gKpj/pirLhdTPxM7b9MuKcRuhCXGE@iPuocgZIW9sIftXj5nYce6heBAT/HBesXcOOExzg3OHckUoW9H97laFacOojOoGIzJoCVjeDxyJ6MjXybOAu5wW2ttE/VzddJ6SD3uRd/OZWIHF7YVCPESFDyW8H0Vfwox8kl4QKvKBd9OdsJB976YAqCuz@nAKtht8MFkaneXZ1QdeRmgDhN@G@0TX1UPhdCr@xBKXFZMqIp1Dv3VyhlRDHLwrk5ywPXvvUJXp4HjA4XM88pUYX9sN@wHD/r@wwa@DYUREtDwOjg0xapoK65q9QYMJW8@h2Rm1wAQtOdpShfx4Rz8AnOkEOAheZGtMK72bSRIdMoGdopWoNLIxZr8AAu8n0pc6wN8b0eGw5lxTcxMgf2CKgjtB4sROyDySCVtjUtnUUZq8dP6JWoEiiZUY8y9aAWR@KQ61TznArc9fGHZ1RHtyI6bqa0@TsgjIV5Vr81qhMO98hlzOUSkqDSDJQdWFYY44eU8fT1j@NaKpokQL3ofFnRMDyt1gYNDQethyapYdrynTJbU7a/WWQnPtKcDrbauOz/gLHPoBNspglZDqLNH0G7uKr0YSIDY/7AszQ/gLnZcOsL1ACWqSVRwFBgtNnnncImE2yYFCG/3Lwt5qBV10W9dDRl8W30I6XCD526uEcnD@d4J96P7hXxMBjohJZEE4EB0xztn9Gg3oVN44Hp3RDcPiT4I4c7sYG/UCVs/FA/CwLxBQDCgc3qTE4iHSqCBJ1Kwl/jEOEI1i7pcc6kRekDbbbpeCmCGxiqZyAE6NhSX/VNqupmedyNPB67J6wpqChjpkQJFlG9psBBLpUrfDKzPIoBN7IBXV3HC8Pr/TvSmkpLdKhYSbweR3bvZdxmopL6X9Iqn7sZU8BqwZNI1AdQZcMt9PvMDsmG11vI8whmOpxhjAgZMfwxtq/I3U1CByjY9zFN/QPwRHrxfX@gReW25lfFi2rZp7H@S6CSgNpl64x9foXuHSBBxuHx5dqPqWARiD0sKYrqlNLr6DJVNvVNATb7vxJPz3yiJ2bpPOHPv3Hz6UvxCcVx4lue6Ld4X7WdkIUo@cpI6qrnGHvlzbOKlbwSs@n1BGtm8rnExSRcl6fuKuUawME/lAh/A8Y9CWnzE5QrjslNbBsh8k8orFhMk3jbhgfNQ36UNbIq/UVetR0JNOmJM2N8YDFflEPFx2O3Rfz3cwdWsNygh94yoZIKxcTMcJXhKIdRMvJocJ09WY1yBb4n3IoFqQBAjxhdWw/kFJbAGdYMNBF3hM87K532pBf5uK6R0TIXRCYO2IzhgP//lyXQfXiZz4CrAY1Ga/3xMuYQJWRGHUxm/KztvuANKmXkj3DqY2SGM4qoUynSmD8ugd1q@kLkINhrG7aXaPU4WGgjNLjnFXMe8ncr8aCc31ChJ7hPWW@nNvOEfw85mw34b1BH5H5Dhi4KvdxsBY84ja8HegLLP3VIiYEnKJ3n0FrVquxk1KRlBDMTLkYGIL6dZvUETYKQLs4hRmtEEYD5otrbJjLOo6urg3RtsKX8y7cN7op26DFK3wkqJrus2qbnpyq@Dx2giR@EXOyHTAFxRbjrsgUkvUge2PiOBZwDEsyEKDcMQ2V0QPcXPMxmj3C78OZtjCOcHlGKkNw1aD5@ziixI@gevDq84BELU4NJ3UpBaw/yoP2pns6BgUfKaED7shvWCo4W99f6zhtAE3B4eyPbM@IvwFFKTH5Ym/mgr7MZ0S3NETLzOQMHOe@kZIvjPAanoMDwC1aJ3PwQKap5Mfxi5oAQzN9q8VjQp6IxMhVz1nZE8W6z5slwKAGb3W5sV0QCTGxReCFty99Krg6GLM9evbjiOnSqLmXBzBg9NADeNUDdnjMBY53pbXPadUf@9gnY57cwM0qJm10WyMjR9a6o81ovowzsg0szHWFTxuHGmEmQnIFM2LFtSBkk1qJ@DcYsPnS4QASnEDWH6PaSHsOqQGeFkkJBq08tWDSFvZDSuWIGdthvXqBq58sNATjJxmGDUi7RaQxdHFysGjjiZK0Zfh1XZTPYLVgqpcZ230XzEFTtj83PpWnZaDJZWQ@DmVgDbQT1mfjUa5xzJA@8MVvzQ7uA3KqhtO66oa/VySsdZhmZFykgomaklOfrPdlx1xomB6qKLTEb073044cVDrpy70MF3QrWGiFuUPrRHnkQ9iUXHkGzQMgZmS@qzZ3XRC5P0i3MObABYHBDmiagM0dCBeYpxNiniyIiTAfSN9j@xRgxPPOwxBUuJWaddbxBOhJgkHr/ASW9ikFOiLu8D13RV6dyqXBK3adXM3zFMV@HuYb4kHIYs5cX3ZYKbTC9HFwluTP6aUeriuA6pWr7OrqaRyoIiB8EIjGezskaHc1uejoIvkAlYUDVKJOcDUItfUgmScELA3qC@B48@fh1NsFRxGwxsi6ttXYjnfQCiIjBKaG/cYXVL8nuaxwBAksqBeyD/AiKA9Od0Beb1gHLjgGC7oLnI9HAC6qfbHXer8OmoVydjvO5CPJtEGEx7FHSjxhdW@GjxDgXMBPjkB9BjYO7qsAixUxyZd0QuJFKLQPDEExqP4478UfcBxHREef@nrDlJQiE6hHIblaNUIQPGvlDYPwRGoytpG7Qtuqjd09W/SRc4/YAeKwetSRPLe9HFzM8hVvGFTks5k2cVQGYovu/M@8hnFignwL1pnL@wrED4Npw@hhS8TZxTHD@gEHiUVOKiKRbqqNthJiu4wBV23YetBRWctwScvX6Va8nn7FcZoCVi@zizNiqKGlbBZGArGzGy82L1zPgms6U9URoQCTUa6qvaGainZ0d9mQ7mTFe06LMk5mkDsSqeZtXUtGmHThBoqBvRyppb94b0hCYRx0dhDIVWGcOOR6nYcV7zROrfgCm/lL5nECpdprGg@tHEID@BRyFnq20M3ThdXLl2tVX/Dk48kXfl0D@mb4mBc4UBoPmF3xdURWjEr420gsmdr@UuYG9ewNaoerzCgp1Yb8tjzHAydYkBPsuS6Emo7jJrLt/hrnFv4OSsckwdWz/lwKJhpUT85DqhAhCzwMfCJqrM7SpjrmmnJn7UaOQqaGuwt1yJ5ZvNZCBV2BjaVvQuV@wXj8HeDVFMJeQGq5IqpF0GZrt/Fogzxmw/O6aqrav@FKA8N2dHCgagUpJU3uzlJQybll@MZVPPJJmddxyI0SIeCKGoLp6qTeIIGtwX5ZSc/dZGdfIwS5Wpo@O9y0RAmNtGZGY@eH1vpLuYSYQgyvl7W2Bw0idtkgwsJtSbq5AsFLAH/FPMjRKXS6c5bbXzTBk7VGA4wYTvo7@QCimYGTRQy/isoIa8PDX8kWiugwfys39RDmuYIcSYGfqpYpIp/De/5b8F@ScIwhJKwFrv@tALo6pILHKZGCn5F2gytQmCp5z/pYc@YA@/AWmP8x/HUCpU7j8DmAY3GLoADr8Q0BriBCGMuwIUNWIDlVMwwC0m9FOfCecfgcMCB8RDyBRVCSDmTqq8rT3diZ1GuFTylN7sqdll@ns7Lg720BRsFhCL12dF@26jpGksA0oeC2QynKqF@Fq0UIguORnkXRZHa50QrKMWbRsE8vOLPrPO1o/ZrxaQQ02FTSNAniFjdA@gv3kT3McNLsgTSWJ4QZ1nBPBy7mq4/zvEGQ4Ewwk6K2YqRpqQIWbOPrDwhz2/qxpQKJ4wlFCfIge/1iLAGjwuXmkjiLsJB6/lsuJ2cu5oNwxrhPBQnlP2b3csRNLuiVerI7XLUACm3eYTQcLdyzwYahcbxmLJzgANPs2Ztl6CHpBtiLicZYV/RG43sm0uzoVE2jPtCoXyfcjcdDmndztM4PpeLTwVyVccXxNY3MebL62LSVchT/HcdjW9w9IdjBHv/ROHyQ/0UsoLPzUu4r3rsZhP44vjAy2jae/OEmPg1/RCm1c@P851FwMbCr4/QyYUGA/soe@gjYTcMQqjoh52HwxpMdOGGJ8C@CcJHgVKBgauMKAinmwm@ix/hKCby5e6jPfqHZwHybBQxe66iIVc/8gPVkbhYhRMs4dFXmc2V5g2t@t9p6QxnLBJVyI8aWotX0RI/YIAnzwcDIOzumC4voq6642GBAd1cNd6szXXmetFhNc9Nqn11QVRuhcYF4MCABbAUWx01sQfhKPG@gTFgaWJTHOvSNJPvV6HG2oq4rxksVvlyCK/da5IEs1tZ7jePs@yKwbS6jDWhSgsysd9F/wVLYQeQ12etZ5/HMzICe2xdCEdZfkDLhBDeG9R8HnQvcS8rI/krtIEloGE9Qm2dEEuCzHBlcX3U9g4b2lvrsDk58MoB692l9KN2nYVXk7noFuLh9kFnRV2QPaid4o2sfT@ccdVeE1ji3/62BTlDNdgTnlvjwj9iDf@SGqQ8u1rW6pLHXZflyQje0AXbZ3Y8025lGPIcSDEv3MHpFwOPnDmP9hmiVCiVf0qR0QPSTlafxeMd0yU189X4paW3lPI4yv1CV8TDSQ5M8v3ue1FowMDdAE3HpMh5W0ox1NG8O5Kp9HDvM5qD67MDdBV3xatM5ksooD29ROV5n62HjeTz@XQkkQbiLgXMrUMPCp662eLebU68ElnTlqBFXDUI7@AEdvS8HVuNLZLTVXuga@4bYzE4Hn2a3mNyvrq8q8WE8PgFPj/NOqHuCrT2Abr/NSe7f0CIah2rYBic601NfxuMCR4jzZGaGXQZmfvz33/8B)

A single slice. This is 99 lines, 100 printable character and 1 line break character each line.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242691/84290)

Answer (score 0):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 10001 bytes

One slice, score is probably horrible, but maybe a bit more difficult to brute-force. The input is taken as a quoted command-line argument (like [this](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@w8CSiWpxSVKAA)).

```
_=''#___+_+;__=__[[(:_:=-%((__>_`___`_)_]_*=_+==`*_______*____-___;]'_'____*;;+_`-____+-__+__)-___*_*_'(+_*;-__'_-____+_*____'_-___*_-_____'**_____+___*__->++__=____<__)*___+)_-__%_*+-_>___,___)_________;+__-__=),_______*__*[__;___'+_+_______(___>-____+;+____]____<_*+_;`)_,_____*<____(_(+(*_;__;__[-__`-__*='_____['_,__;==)+*___+*=____*___,_____-_]______(___+__'/_,__+_'_`__>-+__;+____-___%*__=_[+__*__>_]*_%__(['__-+_%*____'___]_*[_*_+_*____*____;_*____[*`<+[__________<('____*_,__*=,,_______,_*_+_[,____<__'*==_[___(*-__________;;_____+_____)-_<__+_+*____[%_%_%__+_+**]___*____++___;++*-_;](_*__,___)()%____+_-__;_=__*__*`%;_+**=_=;*__']_[*____+_;____)]__-_=+_____;_________-__+__+'__,_+;*_'___=*];_)_-__%+__+*_''_++=*__]____+_,_;_+([__+_*+_*__(`_____[_____*_=,_[-___-+_-;(*______;[__*__'())___,;__,___`____;_']____'*__*_;__,(=_+___`_%___*]+*__*_**_*_%++____+_=___*,_++_=-___+`+____++__]__+__=____**_]%_%_*;_(_______=____-(%__+___%__*_(__%[-]_____=_*+**[__)___*_____*_;_____*____[_*__+[___/_*)__*=(__;___-____)_[]__%_*_*_*+____,'______*__'_'_(__`____%__(+;___,=-__`_-_(__[)_-_+_%_____')____'(__'-____+*'___*__*_;_=____*__+______*__+_**___=**___-_+;__>++[____;_`*_____,[_<___+_*_+_(___]`(+__`___`__(__%___+__]_____%_)______+_+_=*_%`-_____;+___,=__('____,___`=__,____*_____;____*_=*__`]*___+__+____,_=_)'=]__`___-_')=___[_____=_=____-_-]_______]-*_____%_____'**_*_-*________'_____*__;+_________[__*____;[_(_=]______)*_;__;_)=+;___+*<_-_+_______=_+_*____'*____+___-`__)]_,_;_`_+__;;(-___++*____%___;_____+=__'>__*,_____*;+_*____*__=______=_(______<+__,_)_*_,+_____*]_%___-__]__)_*___=-%_,__-______]%_-__*=___*_____'__-__-____=+_*_*_-_____*(__)_____;__*_+_-__+____=+_*_______,<_____[__]__+'*++__]_;*-*___=))+]__+_*;(__*__]______]____(**)+(%)][_*=___;_+-__(__(=_%*___'_++_______+__'),__(=__(_+___-___)__>__+_>(___+-______]_)_>%___+*%_(____)`*_;=+_=-_______(___=]____,*___[_____-__%_->_`_'[____(_(-)++__;=+;*(_;,___*)__%[_;___+_____*_*____%_____*____=_]_____'__]___-_____+_______*_=(_)[_*_%__]_-;*_**_______-%-+<__;-__-____)_`_-_+*_`_+=__;`______=*'_)_)____-)'_]_<_*________)___'-+-_______+___*;__+__[<*_+__=,_;____+==____[__+__=____,,__=_[-____*)=_+_______>]_)_-__________%_*____'_+_(;*___;__*____*__*`___*_'__-___[,+__;__*_______'____[___+<___-_%___%[__'__*__+__-________-___]___-________(*+/__+_''________][*)>_'_>__,_+%__+]_)-+=*<_*______*__;+_'__,_%%_/_)_(]+_%_;;____*__(_(-*_'___(____--__,-_,++___[_)____(__-*+_____+__*____`_=*____;_;<__;``__*+_`__*+_*_______,,;_';-_[_)____-________+]-*,__[](-*__'=+____(________+___*_'_<___,<)'`_[_________*,`=__*_-_*(__+`____%=__''**_[_'__%_[________;>+_(_[+_*____-_*_'_*+____+_(*%__*_____+_=+____+;__<+%,**(__)_,____-+%______'____++'__+_____*_*((___)____+______*_%_-__*_;<`__*____(*__,___>_____+____*__'____[*_%_**___)+_;_+__+_=_**_>_+_+__+___=______]_*__*%____)'__-_____+-__-%__,_**;_(+=_=___+__`_+_____**++___[_*___)_(____[___*;_[_'______*-*_(_____%_-+,_,_*_[__''_*___=__*__(______)_+%,*[=_'_-_'=(_%_=*'*____*___]+_=-_*(_*_];>__`_[__-___*___;++*_`_=__[__*___;[__>_*____,___=__+__=<_______+*+_=_++_,+_*_%_________,___,;_=*_-_-+____________-_[_+____)_*_,___<--_______'_;__(___=__;____*_-)____-_'_%___________)__=__________(_)________=+_[%__=___[_==_=_*]___*___,_[++__=_+=___*+______*___)_[_[_`___-____<_'(___+,_______=_+__%+-%_____++'_____,*<('-_[_(+))__[___]______%+*____;_,__+,_]___*__=%_%*_-(____>+=[_,*__,____-;--___++__=_-(><___++_;)*_*__++__-(=)___`__;______)_=_%*__**_[____=_+)________;*-_`'-*_+;%_-___+_*;___--]____]__=-____**%*_;__*_____)%______,_______+_*_**_,]__-_);________;__*_,_+____*_-(___;___%_+*_(%__*`-_%_*'_*[_____+*=___-__,;_-_*<_>__+_+__)[%_'+(___,=_=*%[_,___'__+__-*-[_____]______-_*_____''_________*_*(`____'_____-_=+(_____'____-(__'-_[____][[__,'-_;_____+______'___=_)%__=_;____*_*__=__(____]_-__+*_*_____++_*__'_]_)_;____=+=__+]*+*+__;,*__[,___+__*)__`+_*__,__]_-_________*(_%_*]__+_--+)%__'=_-_*'__'_______`_**______;<+_)*______-___*_*`_'__%+)_____(+____*_*__+____<%____+___<__+__]*)_+*-___]__;;(_`'___[__%*___=_______]*_'=__>%__*_*__=___[_'_+_,[[=-,_;_=+**___=_`+__;____________'<*_____,_*=__'___-__-___*__*_____-',_______=`__((+**__<+_(*<+(_'`__*__+_)+++___*+*_(_________+_____[____+;<_________*_%_]__<_>_,_+*_`__*_*[____(_*_([[__(_%__(+;__*___[_+;____(__]_)*=_<__]____*'=___,___*'_<__,__*]__=_*__)______)_____*__'(_'____`+___-*____+__*(_____,(>____]_____->__]___*`-____]_____'__]__*_((,+_________'_=___*==;-__`*+_%____=[___(_)]_(_*_%______(-_____[_*__;*____`____)_]__(_<%_;_]'_%=_`_*___-[''_*_]=_[%_;___++____+__+_+_+__**[-]**__[*,_+)_____-__-_]__-__*>__)___*=+*______*__*__+__+`__);_'_______;__*+___**_<__-____)+`_`%__(*__+_-,+__+*___<,_=___%_>*__='____]___*________++__+'_'__)_;_*_--+__+__[____=__)(_=_-'__+__]<-%__'<*=_*_'+____-+%]_=___++'_=(*______[+-___-__[____]___=+____[>_))=,__++_*_____=_*___%_)-_>__(_____*[_+_%%_____=+____<,='_)____(*__'*_*___[_*____+_=;+;__[-+=_-=_;__*))__)=_*+_*`___=__*___*___)[_____*____;_=_**%_-_>_=____;___________%__(/_]*_(__*___,____+;__,__==_;<________*_*___'_+_[___++,+__;+__%__]___*`%__+_______=-_(-_*____;__________(______+____=_;__]-_,(,_%__[__________=%_[_____()+-__+_++_+=+-__/=_*_______,____=___'__________[-__-[*_--**=_*____+__([*___=__=_+_-+*_+_-___-__+__=__*___]__*[_)_-+_____,___'`]___,___[__*)_,>=__-_______*__)<__=-_*%;__==+*_-_%____-_);_____'<___-___[__-_________[__'____=__+_'''__[__>=__+;__(________;_____-+_=_*____=*______;,]*,__*-_++*___]_____*'_*=__=_=__+%__`_,__+_*__*_____]_=[_+__[_>____>(_+_________]__)]_____*_%__`____-________*+___)>+__(+__-=_______>_____+_)_]_*__*(_*_____(___]_*+*___;_)*___]_____+_______*'__%___-__=%,____'+_[_=*________-___+__-____;(>____++_<_'__-__*_+(*);'__++_-__=_--__(_`_*_%-____*____*)___+___+;___%*__=*_',[_____=_;,>_*_;-_>=__[_=_)+__'_(,*_*]<________*_*_(,__-_;_-___(______)[(_)___'*>-_+_](____);__`+_*___*___;___=_=)%+__]_;_-___-____+_[+_;)___[____=_*___)_,>__*_]____+]__==__[_________'_=_**___(__+___;`__+()_____%__[*_=-_*___[+__*<,__-__'-____**+*_;__;+_____*]<__'__(++`____`_-_'______;;__*__[_______]____[(__`___+(_,_;[)'_);___;____)___)+_<_]<_+__'________*____________++_=____++_+__(___'=___________[*____-=___+_]_=**]_[________%_____;__=___%;____(__-___,_+____=_*%__>____,_;[_)>*'_%_(%____*__=;+___%*__(*___=_'(__'_____+)___*___+_;_-__+*>__*__+[__+_*,_)___=)]_)__%________(+_+*___*)+__;+)__*_';,*-)>]_)____]_*__*)(]*__+___>_,[_____===%_*_,____-_;_;*_=__])+__'%=**`______;>__+____+___;[_;_)__)__+*_____`_[__[________*____*_''___*=__=___=*__][_*>]_]_+___=__*___`___+_]_*___,_______'_____-`__%__*__*___;]_=+%__+___']_<'_=__])______]___(_%______'%____+__,_+____[__-___*;__,_*_______*[-__(_*_%_*[__=_+%[)+__+=]__*>`_____+-____;__*__,_+_-_*__*___)_`__*__+_=_=______[_]_+[=_+_*__'-_]_+)[+_'_____-____+_]_______'_____;__[`'__*=*_+_____<_*_+-_(_+_=_++`'________+,_____-__-=`'*+;_='_[___*____(+(,_______*-_)-_;*_*;=-(_=[%_=___=____`____`%___[_+*_(___->+_*_+___+__%%=______+)-)->___;-_<__`)=;___+(__(____*+___`>__')[_+_+%_'];_-____[;--___,=__=____+_;_=__,_____)_]+___(+=-+___=,*++*+____'_____=;*____>+_______<;_**_____,___*_'_'__+(_)_____+__(_=__;____*__*_-_]*___-___]___>]]__=_____%__+__=_______(__%+_______*__-,_+**___>**_*+__)__+=_++*____________(__)____%___+(_+_**_*___+;-;_(___'<_)*`__++,____;,*______=____[)_+__+**_*__+___]_+-_;___%(++___-___[___=_%_;__*_____-_<_-__(_+__-`,__+__]____-+___+_*_+_(%___*'___*_[(++*+__;;*_____+;'____[*__==__+_*'___-_*_+_=*____*)<___[**___+__<__,+-[__*(__]_=_;__;____['___+__;'*-__-)___)_-(-+_+=_*____+______=[__*_'(+=______,+*_)____[_-_]___`_**+(]___`__%__+__+____+__)____[*______[)__;*-_+_<__'___=_=___*____[_)___+,=(___+%__+*__>______%____''_<+_;______-_`]__+[_]_[+(=__%*_____,,*________*__-_=-<-____,(__%;_______]_*+__-__[________-*_=____[]_*__+_+__;;____+++__,_,''__]-___-__]=_<__;_____)%+____-_(_)[_*_+_____,_,_______*_-+____(_______`_*_____==-_(__*__);*____-+_,_=+_________'____]%__-<+=_[____)_________=___'=_________+___;[__>_;_-_+=%___=,__`__*]+___=*________/;)+=___*__(>___+__-)__=_____`*-+__-__*(__[__-<__,__)_]+%_)_+__;_);_+_(_[___,__=*%_=_-___*_____=__=](_=_=____)_+_%+_-_+____[_+_+__(________=__`___'___+=_=______+<;+_+__+_+___'+'_,_;____=__-_+_'_*__++_____*/___%*)__[*_-__)+____'___[_____=___[<*=______-_)___*/=______*_____*_`_*__-`'-[`____'_+______________-____+__%_-+__;__*________-__%,(_______%______,_______(_=___[__+`;*__=_+,';_______+_____'_(]_+))___`_'*________**_;____;_*'________'__=*_______;____(_-)__>_____)_[_(+`*__'__*___**+______+;__;_%_____=__=_]_;_'+/__[______;;)_-<______-___=_;-(*_*[+'_'___[=___%,)*__,____%___*_]''>'_'%_______+__+_;'________',+___*__+**_______-__===______'_____+__'_=_*[____*_%__(__[___*,__,-___(,+__>+__`_`__-]-`__;_=____'[*______+'___]*_*__*___<'[<___'_<_)__+(__*_*_,+;*_*__+(__-_*+___%_=%]____+__*__*__>_)_)=+_(____%__;+;,;_____+]__,_[);*____=_*+_____`___-==*'_>_]'-_<_]=_______'*_+______+__-_=__'_____`_+__)*-_+*_'_,[_+__=__(____**_;__''______`___`_*-_%_________-_++___'__%)+___(]___%__=__=+_____)*-__*[___+_-=_%]____;_____*__>*__**[(_*___+_[;_[_(__'_`____+___;-___**__+)_+*_'`*_=__+<_'___**_=*___=__'+;*;;____**<*____)_______+_+________-__+_____-_+________]_)_*___________+_;_*%_;=*,[__________,____=_<[-___*_____,'__-__*_+_-_'_*_-+_[_--+_+=_[((_+___+_;__;_<+__(=_;+_+____;_<_*__*+_+_;_,_____(_[_*_+____,(_;__-`___;___*_;_'___+=____,_______=_;*'%_[*+__,______'%)=;___*+___;]__[_+_____=_=*_;_+___%'[____-_*_-____<*____[=______*%__,)__>_'___,<____+__>__(__***,__,`__**___+)'+__=__;])__,____%*____%___[__+*______*_'=__]_[;_(;_____*]_%==__%____%,______%`___)_)_*_`*%__'__)_)+_*_-__-_]____+_(__=_______-,______=(*+[_,___-___(_>______*%*=___+_'__[___*_,_*____*___%____,___,_________<_]__%___(,_'<_________+_+_*[=__+-__+;__'*[+])'_____*_*+_;+(___+___+_+___*_=__,__-_=-%_(%_'=_______*____*_)_=_]__*_++]*__'-_)________=[___+__+=%*[__+*++__'__*_______,_+(___+_*__)_*____=_*]'_______+<_*_+__*-__-*__;]_'__<____`,_____%*'_;_=)________;___-____`*_____)*==___-__-_='___<____*__+'____=_=_[___%_)______=____________=__<____(_+*+`___*_(__]____]_%`'[_-[_______''__*______*___[*_-__________>__-=)_;___'___=____',_`___*_*+__,_%[____%____+__*_%____+_)*__'____;*-__*_(_=*+,_=*/+___
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVpJjvY6jjxMQ5BEWsj9k@WLCIaMrk0VUBNQvanTv2ZwkJ35D5mfB4ljMEjlf/77j//919//9pf27//@31//9c8//1wj5/9Za/HivtZYa87yx/pjtFTKWtd65N6z6roXjcVjPLTsS783@dfvvLJe6Z3Xg0uLG1ZctemDtHJhuS2f8rL79rp9Iru2MtnabKu3i1klWuuUpXCPKx5Ni2T9Sz4f8q@u@JLdcXvU4xWRplzH2qzL4kvUWpdJ0fXabVsQr/7UZS/TaY8WLoQF5O@Ud6AdDdV2zYxn@xiVVTYaYRZbotnCtqFslH9wg0XpBwKwCWw2TARNJ@v717pJlFxFdljyXHJbQVLRh8J6@l@3b5Oek@c2xTqLuQRb0jjCIoe@PQ83aqYhu0JEau@7vW83qAtPjQ7bJi380c90hwzwkyjDski/C66pY0pNtk6DmMP88aSOd8caXT7mWyS3h3TTesMew7buWyKLJs5YmOU96Dbo7sviAffkYhZBBrk/WR6VncrUYFOLlcf85rExDnUpLNx68bDuU8XMpSKujm6qPCZOvi1M8QjulKFGemCRRTfrDUK8JzWJ3EVM0AELDezFD4fBbtXJYobWDbNS11jBl15vJZkbEhaWW2m222@TGHFa9JMr1N@8RJQsjYefRRUhUMye6ua65q1phD8q0JF3xiCZi6uMIAQsrAPSP/K23JkwOqvO8rSmX5bL2VKKsieeuVx/5r04L83xof83hRzJ8mnmdWg5JiJOg5zVHvcj6OFApFaw4DRLpAAAJLh4PxkAWW4dIoElgnpxeGrSG16Ed9Zzk61pxhDBax637dlEx7HDZrhnljtCxGjkggSGCZ4FSBowYsPOO5pnpO4UbYavUx1m6lCDswBQ25A1NmBSZGZ7NFsQ5A8u9F40wCxP004fFnnzpUFoGP2Cx4jFPehOhu4VoGEbS4Yni5l76XV5uCXY0NFColYBcds06y29O1jjy56kEkDdl/q1ua2HiwOzn2EdpEYmS5JOasxRK2vGUC@6mZtNvxWiyiXVe5osXeuPPCcJquCZDaLcdhkFoiA0zJJWRC7cu4oXL1u7rkuDjZLZqEqI9uG5HNBuHjxox4iWqIbSmadXkVYhgLzaxRIdrkBWpqlOcmMvesOIzDF3GPWO1N0hIYFbVkWeJ9xunRaFJVtqLMbsbec7Ulci49Fw6I87XnK1mltazbLIuX2hV3MLS1hJ7vp9nqTAdViACSVwrwWaodgMg1bRcmyJr9vgOr5ScADJctQCCw1Hj0e/WzhJveL3biQVTAst5QnYTGyJ64Y27VM4PrbTUOEfLcI5rtyT6iWvXlpcALgiZ5NCsq1h2avFJyUB1LrKDfzrjiDqYCtKGiVNdjuaJBGrmNUDpRnULnZFHoUeKNbhrEdUlifs/50TUoGy@NFX2WqwoI6Yed7YeGUrmGV9vSXynJpVNT/rZQZ0PMMoF3KSDeaBEUCuCSXS@3S/gMCTg@xhUfLKViiFR9grNpDr5HSQpbsiTuP0cRqjhu94B8M0xXaFMEARizy@eHE2cb3RTxEBeFyDvoI@sNVbuXBpMdCHR6QygkolqXmnEvIjKSlC5WXDdi01LiK5C3UPs@@0TJgrKmYjN7yIzocyLIRiNrj0@PCcgm3mUNqbJX0TUnBTuVtxhcCf7n5BirmcHxu7QsTs6gGicpmJDtsI@XdGBBBMIdIfbAix@Z@SmgH/t7ciqXOnaV2NNK6ztZ1u3ZFuF83m4Zg/a6srx/upvNRcwkOY47IyOmDnTR6FhBnNZ60iL1UAS5E/T4T9qSxj8fGpicKzmgmggaUwLMwXuhQGg5trV4rEnm2HLuL7j4QK0dRDF4@pOG6B21tzqjbkgeu0D70qUONyK6MaKemhv9UbzSQTcZtA6th6sgQLd41xLWUKFrfXMSsqRIlerKvp9Vv0TbL6oTS5boLcjel7dqg2XSNSdAaHpAcgKXBP08NjmFklFhp6ncv4kxSUJK1SMeo0SED1sNSFutTmW3MNDjQ88gsuEr7PS3vA5Mub/M1Y4jTUnWCdbX17DeP1qvSISDOeUmzfpkTfQYcNCFBVugUZkuAmxL7UWFrW57DV2oe9L7k/NYiQg6S8ojXGvnlArxwawLtRVrvwo0pvXSFUKeClO7nwllh/OlNodhpfFTGYvCIJXZNwMDxJ9AIVWj@RQXlHKK9gI6k852iouoONREOnT5ME@50Ubd4wFdqGELvT8s4fkOmiS51A81NclR@voEJXtIgwvVXFnTQN6c@P0xM0QhAdRjIguTMfeR@eLruVMJqkHBdLi/dE1NODiqC6hhxp9TqUgwIudp9fd59SzEfaUbXgxWTiHuV6I1WomKW7tQZfUiXilePFwWz92higTg95kzOmodmt@nhGlrZ2o9W9nqt4N54V3/d1Z1TWR1VuUyvCPQCEPXpmq1KaedLNtRvOmGgXa0SZDhFQEi/v9Qa/rMQiDTVcoCB/sICtqTyD/8kjT7JaKpF@WL8sLjtU37QuBFoO42wSyNZ056UpRsgRo4DeodYCaDR0uE8gsQQgnJXZS/9tJVUWGdFhTyWVzVe5rTrg@rVqHUck9nK3o8HTYY85llClUoqqokqM7ByLtEGiXbLBBzrr6EawoSmmEMpCHUqynl2hreDM9RmrgEkAqS9LzW@ewZQ/yNTymfewzQqkur25YcIgeZWt8uFDnxQBmV5CL/BfWmz@KaJv6qn8txDLcmCFz7RnBGcr1SZvYkMe@PFnvFwy5govXitLbxOeJRphM0lZRyTU2Mber3nP5ga71Rc1WISWief2n6Zi7nGNl7Iig0/VkhIGjYhjY@5vJcunQ@v8UN01XeJhvD3rFSzN/cN5bYXGHjXOrVEIbjBlwV1rjS37UQqHd/MgqI@N5jZM3kh6jXTFkausFyRuG1M58lnab2k19erFVg5aoHqw1@pMtPg@xbgpW/tTXwF3m5dX9OAjqQczgmnQt8OJjqcb6onzT2@dxHWFas96sSmT0c4YoJTajnYUSN1ScVmHkZLER4w8@gGmKZh4Kf8c4NuYEkmNpftXsBedDXQVJ1jvNCKY6cJA47ZGukdFXt75wRc1Wcsf0QaZJijX2phjxPDAQMPnfLfm3CcbsjUBKoAOJsVDXGpkrsT2sDzTcetp04zs5IttDBPzj1Njr7D1SY8y3j0jpXdXFWX62EwKqZTpKY2GxnWPslXhF1mSPylI3/LNNi/U7DX75Q@f9klpsyblxhDtftVOkQWK6FFemyakowf6n8uSVbqHehHYe0kxDVKl4fti2a9DPZMrpoxsvmG6VgwYGZOlqhMaMLG3Hyg@M6aqoFe1JRVa1qoOAnZTVsvtjOlaEXFjJO9CNJqkvopWt0ZdErWf6E49T9j6IYyD8dcrpPZP85ehyciqpb5hBGZGItAd3SJ5JWcTbzNvZ7SPD2MtbMUJ7BCe73VmE/MNiRLmyMEF3RnR2XUbybuIsy2nGKBPAr5pQmfGhImuZzetMQw5FJgp2qUgbyPI5IRa04eHGVSC6@RNzl3Lr36olaClNMghCFMQbjoqQ0P57MjlY3OU8WQS5JA6PMPShcs@hWmo4JhP9SEtwBACNILwWlol44TGNdtlk181V0quCtdWweOAQpKUTx3dMs1gRmH3uTDbA26LU/JtMLKm9XGH@1xjOAbBwGNWaYfWsXFIx289qOk5jNpdAcdnj3bg8BlLVilqgHb5NMk6ZbnpM4a67juYfnoHZpaq6Z3sCUVbxvEvsgl91UEu8y@4iJlqMkuwHT0AxJsdJEg9rUgWNl9pT7QPF2ZV8ki7YbnhZ8X/wvwWYvS0b0MK6zefnLbneAfxjd@ZffLChVFIMYP27l1bj9GNojbbc03fG16LTn3AJ/LoAhiNJ2m3MPwwTo/f9IGe0VPpQELYSGlgPpvJBH3XE0g39iFWrJYedkSHFo@L/eR@CVipL@6qxbSN53VGqzreAxctocfQGUUyELo@0CzAc3Iwu7ZAlRj5ORmT6ORBddAHr6R9bmezdiYw3fnCS6CXdT/m0tt8yXGGp13cIX12VuJoo3xtt7qPF/wE0kfJweXeA9T2a7L4BDMfzblvNb82HLeNbyNlpwOrnWwnjJ9z2vG7sPGeZiFjeSRNRHUGaXa@ZOenV3aTK9Vhc7yt9VAzuyBSALDWQCLFcUikvXLteqY0LYEHAYraLsOAiLsEfuKVxHEKM9cuyvHs44ryBlw@O0dPB6aWl0/JlQgDeSk6v0U/Wm6rxldTduDrzW2ledKIiNEa/DO@tIHMIe3JbT4xS1@/p3qOo@rIzwhdDymO8os8bLcXnzpIa9l1BMFH7r@GAEL@UExs/JXfoPVDyG5pHaGwHei0pNXIjaqTuodido9M9H00z9P2i/LCjOH9DAZW1cWhpiBDKxg8WMe6phKho8Y8T0FJevJ8ZS/H0X/3V9bDf/eA37MUpSPfGslOMeduAYqPhQ@d@8tnLHPpIFnc0u72rDgNzQEmOq@8Kar3meepO5yK9cXo9IHDbrLPzYqcRGy632MERZmKU0MLzQSu1Q@fqt06X/UcHTFd1ZHqwOnPJfYAot@RjTkwwHqKETrrRLySHiJl0DR@x3Lm9JgC2jEttc9guFnIo5PRIFeotXGwQwZWNoMy@K0puI@zLx2pzuIUdGL6rtz02fDRTA4wVUj4KCCydkG4PryfzWJPP7UhG5XV9Z4e//plA5P77fnqL6oOJBfw6IOOTxvuHfY5X0g5dh@mvYMC6tRBCnCxFCc6Guw4f5Vi0F2WbudxxHr/8MzcMC3J242QqqXgBAejTybLaiTBPon3tZyMO2kwCIONuT9gj@wYZSU7uGxxfmu2mgE@ODPRFM772JaXz2iINA0e84c4JFuodPBiS8R9zjk3V1829bzh3NL34TMST@MoufDpUZ/BGQ/E0NFUZZOzxW9@lJdYNX9xFGIbZltreoUqZO1U9hQOOk6BisfHmmAjt10XdpvPTziICDCPTl@QDQJDd43Df/xmEZdosf14zjho0xN1YUy7IPr21Y5/xdl8G3t/T1OmI9dIpCZk3vhpIvtmFKf2euASKMenhZDSJtIYyMqzJHFN00Q48hn1O1tpVmI9XceI8aSODc/49Y4cvyMxv7@a8W1i8cF/t0oEt2Pe4hxSPP5I5LVIqfwqRSvq5HpHKm3Y6D/HHvlYT1gcp7VzFzdeMbq1IX6OMxndfpAw5EE/8Myff/4/)

Comment: Unless `_=_[::-(_>\`_\`)]` (given by `code[12:42:2]`) is the answer, I honestly have no idea.

Comment: @AnttiP that fails for inputs like `" abc"`, where the string is not larger than it's representation. I think I'll add some hints later today, this might be a bit too hard.

Comment: that's what I thought, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 235 bytes, 1 slice

```python
#xn=t'(esvtarl('s.turp(pienrp(u)t.(l)o[w:e:r-(1)].[t:i:t-l1e]([):.:l-o1w]e[r:(]));)e)v#axl=('xe)v(a'lx'#.'u*p7p0e-r0(+)0.-l2o+w2e-r4(-)4.+t8i)t;lper(i)n.tl(oswterr((s)t;re(vianlp(uxt)(()'[x:#:'-*17]0[-:0:+-01-]2[+:2:--41-]4[+:8]));)p)r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BisQgEEUPk4VVLSWaCXRTTZ9EXGQhjCBGTCWxT5@RWf33eZtXv/K7lZ/7nnr5iIK4n7K2DGo3crQKNcUy5kAxkHHzF0duBA6D8cKJhbKLATyy4Uybu0L0jSEgvjHiOa09f0D1gbCq3NVk1PGoz2ojNQsaraE8b/qax1@AcDFaXgnlnWtskLAYybDtl8TWAPYhWoQzrSWPqC4IgMp3nljRwz2D9cSWNVlHYfaaZyZaBi@DX/9RFdt9/wE)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242744/84290)

Comment: @AnttiP not intended. but i changed my answer.

Comment: [Cracked again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242814/84290)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1121 bytes

```python
c#5c#cl#7a#cs#5s#s #9P#5r#si# n#it#te#8r#r:#2
#e #a #8 #2 #s@#ss#tt#1a# t#1i# c#7m#ie#5t#2h#oo#5d#2
#h #i #  #5 #3d#te#3f#1 #oa#s(#fb#8l#2a#rh#6)#1:#2
#2 #l #7 #2 #2 #l #a #4 #tr# e#7t#3u#3r#4n#  #:b#bl# a# h#9[# :#3:#4-#61#1]#2
#r
# 
#9c# l#
a#1s# s#s #lI#7n#ip#du#et#3H#8a#8n# d#8l#7e# r#::#n
#  #b #1 #7 #8@#rs# t#1a#5t#9i#5c#7m#@e#rt#ch# o#cd#6
#n #1 #o #a # d# e#5f#t #la#o(#ea#8,#  #6b#8,#c # c#4,#8 #ad# )#c:#5
#4 #5 #8 #1 #3 #3 #e #  #ct# r# y#d:#1
#7 #a #4 #5 #6 #8 #7 #: #  #8 #e #3 #1a#
+#ub# +#cc#r+#
d#4[#71#5:#a4#6:#s2#
]#5 #t #5##d #11#a-#:1#1-#41#8-#71#t-#81#6-#61#
-#e1#a-#41#1-#51#3
#e #: #3 #  #t #I #8 #4 #se#3x# c# e#3p#et#1:#m
#7 #2 #, #t #9 #  #  #1 #b #: #- #5 #4p#,a# s#4s#8
#t #5 #5 #3 #2 #9 #4 #1 #,r#te#5t#4u# r#rn#: #-i#:n#ap#[u#:t#3(#6)# 
#  #s #) #8 #7 #3 #: #+ #:
#9
#np#1r#7i# n#7t#l(#6P# r#3i#Pn#2t#te#:r#2.#8a#2(#)O# n#lp#7u#7t#8H#4a#8n#7d#sl# e#rr#t.#4a#1(#2N#io#9n#2e#2,#  #:N#1o#5n#8e#5,#5 #5N#6o#2n# e#t,#f #5N#-o#on#8e#5)#+)# )#5 #  #)##7 #ra#2r#,g#3h#a #1t#2y#5p#7o#h
#(e#1x#3e#7c#4(#8"#5p# r#5i# n#2t#8.#3_#8_#ic#6a#el#9l#9_# _#9(#3i#cn#rp#ru#4t#9(#()#p[#7:# :# -#e1#o]#5)#n"#5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZPNbpxAEITvPMUo3wW0u5b4hzn5mFwc3y3LYgFnkQiggZXip3e624mEEBq6q6uqa7aP47Yu@ednT9nTz9Qd/U65szvaZ8rAPuEWpoNjpAkETxYxOjpH48gc@yP7znGQdjh5S31P/ZtppDzIbqwr5aBdN8fkcI7SkQ8KmL@TOtaOPeb9SjOTdYQbVUJqgwR/dtQ26Otb5haOI@BG6oP8Th4oFoX1V64zTmjcaF9wntxTXKhS0ldFCxEuou1xM1FHuuNM6fyDWjRuDHdGwfxO09EI5qCU6hEX8J4l0ilXp5yFUvNI2E1yp0rbST0U4Y8j4aC/4Vb6gSpisZbVyAumMC/fOWRuxxozyqyzIldX/eidGlic1d5OihN6Txmp6tI8F6jcntHM7A@l5z4YPGmkxL4skuLK6uXEW2VjLdIohKMT9yvuRN8TTkQDxQt1SunpCirPnhG9KojwLGGQrpTughczLxQpzUXrjwtNSmUmRxdGqymspkzJLSrehjqD@mE0hN4u2/@jSsWNfFPbZeO/o3@7Pltxa13OJF8N52K6io1zp7srdprIGH6Fynpbw5eWc9CMyWqKu1oUFkOY8AvdxssdL7uONWzONitJSP47ltu4k7wlMLLBjTRQ212Q1M3S9ayY@cTzQma3wweyB01OFpP81Mp5o75rffOdwhJVD@yzSg7C7UEP05jsiWmlFZyRzJLgn0jl1iw0wv9s6p6oVrJFe48z73ZyWVm/ahJOiUalNLsSVEIQJoHzL/KbRiKVy/hBKZRWbhHxSPqHXC6RhC2m@aa/RFFpGkVR80D@RvPG1FN1jDOtPG@4N9pYhfcLYSPcKQ49iRM2iZDXe@csCeurElsEOYk@P/8C)

I hope this is hard. One slice.

Comment: To be sure, the intended solution is not `[4::5]` (which only contains two mistakes that could be rectified with one byte each)?

Comment: @ophact No. Can you please send a link to the result?

Comment: [TIO link to result](https://bit.ly/3rNFAhZ)

Comment: [Cracked the new version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242827/106710)