# Slice the source code (Robbers)

Tags: cops-and-robbers

[Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242616/slice-the-source-code-cops)

## Robbers

Robbers, your job is to find the slices of the corresponding cop's code.

### Scoring

The robber with the most cracks wins.

### Example

Take this code:
`iimmppoorrtt  ssyymmppyy;;pprriinntt((ssyymmppyy..iisspprriimmee((iinnppuutt(())))))`

The slice here is [::2], so the robber's post could look like this:

````
Cracked <somebody>'s answer
```iimmppoorrtt  ssyymmppyy;;pprriinntt((ssyymmppyy..iisspprriimmee((iinnppuutt(())))))```
The slice is [::2].
````

Comment: Add the link to Cops thread

Comment: ok.............

Comment: `The unsliced program must be valid code, and` your example isn't

Comment: @l4m2 well, any suggestions?

Comment: @BgilMidol Suggestion: `#iimmppoorrtt  ssyymmppyy;;pprriinntt((ssyymmppyy..iisspprriimmee((iinnppuutt(())))))` Slice: `[1::2]`

Comment: @AidenChow But that code check prime rather than reverse

Comment: @l4m2 That's what OP's original example did anyways, I'm merely just adding a `#` in front to make it into a comment.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [cracks Sisyphus's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242635/84290)

```python
input((input()[(-1)::1-1-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvoLREQwNCaUZr6BpqWlkZ6gJhrKbm//8eqTk5@Qrh@UU5KYoA)

Given by the slice `c[-2158:-4855:-93]`

I was initially surprised to find that there were no characters besides those used for `input()[::-1]`. The `input()` is a dead giveaway though and a brute force search reduced the input to a handful of possibilities. I then just looked at them individually until I found the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 181 bytes

[OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242621/84290)

```python
if   True:  print =eval ('  exit')# not  open   u 
exit or  ( eval)('14')
# NO
   
open  or 15* id(  int( int(int (int( id(  print( print([111][:123][:55555-11111111111]))))))))#11;
```

The slice is simply `program[::6]`, giving us:

```python
irp=(input())
print(irp[::-1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xC8IwEIX3/IpnOyQRHM5ah0p3J10Eh9JB2oiFkJSQiv76mLQF33DHPT7evfHrX9YUIXR1lmXDE8DNTaoCRjcYj1q9HxqCA@ozeC5zGOsBOyoT0Qks2bAOEEioFJwOXLIclyuLBFvICFC5xdALIMaKeaR8sVzJnx@KdTVE1DYV7Ys4y6Qd/dXKVTnRKfZuqurYsthFdaKTIZyV1hZ363S/@QE)

Answer (score 3):

[-3::-14](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242636/)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
import sys as s
s.stdout.write(s.stdin.readline()[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4slghsVihmKtYr7gkJb@0RK@8KLMkVQPMzczTK0pNTMnJzEvV0Iy2stI1jNX8/98jNScnXyE8vygnBQA)

I admit that I used tools

Comment: Ah was hoping it would trip people up for a little longer. What tools?

Comment: @jezza_99 Python

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), cracks [emanresuA's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242641/78850)

```
ż⇩İ
```

Generated from a slice of `[1:15:6]`

Comment: Yep, intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), cracks [EmanresuA's second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242645/78850)

```
ɖ‡$"t¤+f
```

Given by the slice `[11:33:3]`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, cracks [AnttiP's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242628/64121)

`[53:586:4]` results in:

```python
def g(o):exec("".join(map(chr,map(sum,zip(map(ord,"ikbgm!bginm!\"T33&*V\""),99*[o])))))
x=0
class f:
 def __del__(self):g(x)
y,x=f(),7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY29CsIwGAD3PEWaQb6UDxE6iIXuPoDoYCW0zU@jSVMahdSXj9RbDm65eX2PYapylkpTA4HXKqkBGNs/g53AdzMM44Kb48fj187/FhaJzL5644ve2MkXLbtU1a68toxxPJ3Ke3jwDZKaAxlcFyPVNaHbRQipnBAQldO8NpA4WTE1Gjgecz4r5wLSW1icLH4)

`g` increases each codepoint in `"ikbgm!bginm!\"T33&*V\""` by its argument and then executes the resulting string as code. For `o=7` this executes `print(input()[::-1])`.

When the program is done running the garbage collector deletes `y`, calling `g(x)` in the process.

Comment: Wait, that was the solution? I had found it many times, but I glossed over it every time!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes, cracks [Aaroneous Miller's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242626/78850)

```
wRh
```

Obtained from a slice of `[13::-5]`. Ngl you should have used that one quirk that only you know about because I know quite a few vyxal quirks too.

Comment: You only need to get the last char

Comment: @Fmbalbuena But then the code won't reverse the input string...

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [Actually cracks l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242624/84290)

```
,[>><,]<[.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9rOzkYn1iZazyb2/39DI2MTUwA)

The slice is `c[1::3]`. And yes, I literally just bruteforce copy-pasted different slices to TIO, until I found a solution.

Comment: Do you brute-force manually?

Comment: @l4m2 here I thought that since the code is so short, I might as well do it manually, since there were only like 4 slices I had to check, so it was faster than to write a brainfuck interpreter and bruteforce automatically. But for example for Sisyphus's answer I wrote code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes, [cracks ths's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242662/84290)

```python
i=input();a=len(i);exec("for n in(i*8**9) [1:]:i=(i*a) [::~a]");print(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrRNic1TyNT0zq1IjVZQyktv0ghTyETKKJloaVlqakQbWgVa5VpC@QnAjlWVnWJsUqa1gVFmXklQF3//3uk5uTkK4TnF@WkAAA)

Slice used: `code[4981:-201:67]`

If you want to see the code finish <s>within your lifetime</s> a bit faster, change the `8**9` to `2` or any other positive even number.

Comment: input a 5 letters string, the revert could be done in a few minutes on my laptop as I tested yesterday. So This should finish within your lifetime without changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes, [cracks Bgil Midol's second answer (original version)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242743/84290)

```python
print(str(str(input()[::-1][::-1][::-1])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eo7ikCIwz8wpKSzQ0o62sdA1jkUlNTU2F//89UnNy8hXC84tyUgA)

Slice is s[40:-10:2]

Fastest crack in the west?

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 45 bytes, [Cracks Big Midol's second answer (new revision)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242743/84290)

```python
print(str(str(input()[::-1][::-1][::-1][:])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69Eo7ikCIwz8wpKSzQ0o62sdA1jUclYTU3N//89UnNy8hXC84tyUgA)

Slice is `code[145::2]`

Comment: Not intended, and there is a simpler slice.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, cracks [Bgil Midol's third cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242823/106710)

```
[1011::3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZRfa6RYEMXf/RSX/T1E6e6w1/99YSAwuzCBJRvYxxCCrSYtOCpXmySfPlt1ewZE9Fp16pyqUy6f23mesq@vdu56883c3Ny0FC3tSNXQrhQrq@H4SOFZB8zEsLH11B7vSCN6Q2OoDalhvWNd2TZsg5G7xLdUPxl6io30zDxTdJp1NgwGYygMWaeA2SvWMDesMa8n6pG0wZ8pE2woJPijoQqFrs9SNzdsHtNTbWQXMk8@Kaw7cRoxQuPM8QnjyBz5gdJinxXNR5iIY4sZiRrsiglKx3sq0bjQXegF8wd1Qy2YnVKqeozHOaZIq5yMchZK9R1@DZIbVXoctIci/K7Hb7RnzEzbUUZMIWUO5AVTmBevbFK3YY7ppdZekcuTPrRGG5jvtb2NBCe0jiJS1UXouUBl4epDM9tN6ZlPOoeNlNi1RRJchng5cSGyDimSKISjHZcTZkfb4ndEHfkTlaVwNDmlY02JnhVEeBbQSZalOeCkmQdyS33Q@O1AbSlDk6MDfYjJQ0xhyYJVXChqAtR9oCH0Vpn@hyqVbmSLtl0m/jP6Net9CD6GLBMknwLOIejKF/aNzi5fqaPA8GqqkHsM@JKy9@oxGU1@0Rb5KSAMuIlm4emCk1nHajYTJitOSH53LAvldnIXw8gEF6ynCrsgrhsl61Exs4HHiTRsh/Okt@qcNCb5VyPHheqi8fUP8uCoqmMdVbIXbrd6aGPSB4aZo@D0pMEJ7gErWzNRC/99UPdAOZNOmrvteQ0nh5n5GpOwS9QqRWhXgkrwwsSzfyM7qyWsLOMnhVCaOUfEPfaDTJZIzBZT/6GfRFERNIqi@pbshfqFoaVs6EeOcr1gXjjGKryd8Av@Qr7pSZywiIWc7p0JTpifldgkyEkk/5iv//65//73X/LD0f/Ok/3TWuey5yha/DBt8fVrEvUfffv75eu9f3t/e39v/gc)

The result of this slice is:

```py
exec("print.__call__(input()[::-1])")
```

Comment: Nice work. There is a simpler version, though.

Comment: @BgilMidol It includes a typo, right?

Comment: I hope not......................