# Optimize for Bgil Midol's slicing scoring

Tags: code-golf

In [Bgil Midol's question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242616/), the score of a sequence of slice is defined as

> sumof|startslices|∗2+sumof|endslices|∗2+sumof|stepslices|∗3

Such scoring method makes multiple slices possibly take less score, e.g.

- `[::25]` 75
- `[::5][::5]` 30

Given the length of a string, an upper bound of number of slices<sup>1</sup>, and the one slice it equals to<sup>2</sup>, output a way of slicing with lowest score. You can assume that the result after slicing isn't empty.

```
6 1 [3:4]         -> [3:-2]
6 9 [3:4]         -> [:-2][-1:]
1000 1 [::25]     -> [::25]
1000 2 [::25]     -> [::5][::5]
1000 9 [1::25]    -> [1::5][::5]
1000 9 [5::25]    -> [::5][1::5]
9100 9 [90::91]   -> [::-91][::-1]
```

Shortest code in each language wins.

<sup>1. Notice that `[:]` is a valid slice with no effect to score</sup>

<sup>2. It can be proven that every sequence of slice can equal to one slice for a fixed string before slice</sup>

Comment: "It can be proven that every sequence of slice can equal to one slice." Is this true with negative indices? If so, what one slice is equivalent to `[::-2][::-1]`? (Similarly, can the input slices contain negative indices?) Test cases containing ends should probably also be supplied.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I'm quite sure that is true as long as the length of the string is known beforehand (which is the case here and in the related challenge). The *step* of the combined slice is the product of all steps, so in your case either `[1::2]` or `[0::2](==[::2])` depending on the parity of the length of the string

Comment: Ah, I missed the length being supplied.

Comment: What is `startslices`, `endslices`, and `stepslices`? And what does the `[::]` notation mean? This seems underspecified, or at least it requires some background knowledge not provided in the question.